# How can I parse a YAML file from a Linux shell script?

Tags: shell, yaml

I wish to provide a structured configuration file which is as easy as possible for a non-technical user to edit (unfortunately it has to be a file) and so I wanted to use YAML. I can't find any way of parsing this from a Unix shell script however.

Comment: not directly your question, but you might want to look at ansible if your shell scriting is especially about dealing with remote management of different nodes (and a yaml inventory)

Comment: Try using `yq` to read/write yaml files in shell. The project page is here: http://mikefarah.github.io/yq/
You can install the tool with `brew`, `apt` or download the binary. Reading a value is as simple as `yq r some.yaml key.value`

Comment: @kenorb JSON != yml/YAML

Comment: I found closely related functions [pkuczynski's github](https://gist.github.com/pkuczynski/8665367) of which the best (for me) was that from [jasperes's, maintained in his own github](https://github.com/jasperes/bash-yaml)

Comment: @swe actually `json == yaml` but `yaml != json`. Meaning yaml is a superset of json.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

My use case may or may not be quite the same as what this original post was asking, but it's definitely similar.

I need to pull in some YAML as bash variables. The YAML will never be more than one level deep.

YAML looks like so:

```
KEY:                value
ANOTHER_KEY:        another_value
OH_MY_SO_MANY_KEYS: yet_another_value
LAST_KEY:           last_value
```

Output like-a dis:

```
KEY="value"
ANOTHER_KEY="another_value"
OH_MY_SO_MANY_KEYS="yet_another_value"
LAST_KEY="last_value"
```

I achieved the output with this line:

```
sed -e 's/:[^:\/\/]/="/g;s/$/"/g;s/ *=/=/g' file.yaml > file.sh
```

- `s/:[^:\/\/]/="/g` finds `:` and replaces it with `="`, while ignoring `://` (for URLs)
- `s/$/"/g` appends `"` to the end of each line
- `s/ *=/=/g` removes all spaces before `=`

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at, but if you mean this doesn't work for all YAML, you're right. That's why I opened with a few qualifications. I just shared what worked for my use case, since it answered the question better than any other at the time. This can definitely be expanded.

Comment: a bit open to code injection too, but as you said is a step forward

Comment: I've only ever written shell scripts to use locally, so that hasn't been a concern for me. However, if you know how to secure it and/or would like to elaborate, I'd definitely be grateful.

Comment: One-level-deep yaml has many forms — values can be split to following indented line; values can be quoted in multiple ways the shell will not parse; everything can be written on one line with braces: `{KEY: 'value', ...}`; and possibly others.  Most importantly, if you intend to evaluate the result as shell code, that'd be very insecure.

Comment: If you have `---` at the top of your yaml file, use this expression to remove it: `sed -e '/^---$/d;s/:[^:\/\/]/="/g;s/$/"/g;s/ *=/=/g'` The `/^---$/d;...` is the extra bit.

Answer (score 426):

Here is a bash-only parser that leverages sed and awk to parse simple yaml files:

```
function parse_yaml {
   local prefix=$2
   local s='[[:space:]]*' w='[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' fs=$(echo @|tr @ '\034')
   sed -ne "s|^\($s\):|\1|" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s[\"']\(.*\)[\"']$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\(.*\)$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p"  $1 |
   awk -F$fs '{
      indent = length($1)/2;
      vname[indent] = $2;
      for (i in vname) {if (i > indent) {delete vname[i]}}
      if (length($3) > 0) {
         vn=""; for (i=0; i<indent; i++) {vn=(vn)(vname[i])("_")}
         printf("%s%s%s=\"%s\"\n", "'$prefix'",vn, $2, $3);
      }
   }'
}
```

It understands files such as:

```
## global definitions
global:
  debug: yes
  verbose: no
  debugging:
    detailed: no
    header: "debugging started"

## output
output:
   file: "yes"
```

Which, when parsed using:

```
parse_yaml sample.yml
```

will output:

```
global_debug="yes"
global_verbose="no"
global_debugging_detailed="no"
global_debugging_header="debugging started"
output_file="yes"
```

it also understands yaml files, generated by ruby which may include ruby symbols, like:

```
---
:global:
  :debug: 'yes'
  :verbose: 'no'
  :debugging:
    :detailed: 'no'
    :header: debugging started
  :output: 'yes'
```

and will output the same as in the previous example.

typical use within a script is:

```
eval $(parse_yaml sample.yml)
```

parse_yaml accepts a prefix argument so that imported settings all have a common prefix (which will reduce the risk of namespace collisions).

```
parse_yaml sample.yml "CONF_"
```

yields:

```
CONF_global_debug="yes"
CONF_global_verbose="no"
CONF_global_debugging_detailed="no"
CONF_global_debugging_header="debugging started"
CONF_output_file="yes"
```

Note that previous settings in a file can be referred to by later settings:

```
## global definitions
global:
  debug: yes
  verbose: no
  debugging:
    detailed: no
    header: "debugging started"

## output
output:
   debug: $global_debug
```

Another nice usage is to first parse a defaults file and then the user settings, which works since the latter settings overrides the first ones:

```
eval $(parse_yaml defaults.yml)
eval $(parse_yaml project.yml)
```

Comment: Cool Stefan! It would be amazing if it could turn the yaml `-` notation into native bash arrays too!

Comment: That should be quite easy to do if you change the printf line in the awk script. Note though that bash does not have support for multidimensional associative arrays so you end up with an array + a single key per value. Hmm, should probably move this to github...

Comment: This expects the standard yml indentation of 2 spaces. If you are using 4 spaces, then the variables will get two underscores as delimiter, e.g. `global__debug` instead of `global_debug`.

Comment: This is far from being YAML. And much care must be taken while writing it as the format is very restrictive and have a number of hidden caveats waiting to bite. But I guess it answers the need of reading some value in some format that has vague similarities with YAML. Shouldn't we encourage the use of standard and thus encourage use of YAML ? Besides, the title of the question is about parsing real YAML from shell, and a lot of readers are looking for that.

Comment: Hi vaab - While I'm sure you're correct that many readers would like to parse real YAML files from shell, it's not quite clear (at least to me) what the result would be. With this script I've taken a stab at the problem and defined a subset that has a reasonable mapping into standard variables. There is certainly no pretense of having addressed the larger issue of parsing real YAML files.

Comment: I suggest to add ``-e 's|`||g;s|\$||g;' \`` between first and second lines in sed command to avoid inyection of substitution commands when reading YAML file

Comment: To strip leading and trailing whitespace from the value; add this line between vn= and printf of awk ::

```gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", $3); gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", $3);```

Comment: @StefanFarestam You can find a wrapper of your snippet [here](https://github.com/ash-shell/yaml-parse). If you create a repository, I would love to read it.

Comment: It only prints the output on screen. How would you access the values later on?

Comment: If you're stuck on bash, I implemented a slightly more capable parser in pure bash here: https://github.com/binaryphile/y2s

Comment: How do you access the values?

Comment: @Charlie the values are accessed as normal shell variables. In the example above `echo $global_debugging_detailed` would yield `no`

Comment: @StefanFarestam: when you say "Bash-only", do you mean to say that it doesn't depend on outside utilities, or that it will not work in any shells other than Bash?

Comment: @iconoclast I've only tested it in **bash** but it might work in other shells (with some minor modifications). As to bash-only, it's not quite true as it relies on **tr** and **sed** in addition to **bash**.

Comment: Could you give a breakdown of how your function works?

Comment: This is awesome and did exactly what I needed. However, it breaks if you have a yaml key with a `.` character in it (I have a special case where I needed this). I fixed this by changing this line:
`local s='[[:space:]]*' w='[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' fs=$(echo @|tr @ '\034')`
to this:
`local s='[[:space:]]*' w='[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]*' fs=$(echo @|tr @ '\034')`

Comment: @Anthony the character `.` is not an allowed character in bash variable names (they need to match the regexp `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*`) which is why I left it out. Weird that you got the parsing to work...

Comment: @StefanFarestam that's correct. I should've clarified that I wasn't creating bash variables and was just parsing data on the fly. I actually ended up not using this for my original purpose but I'm keeping it in my back pocket in case I need it in the future.

Comment: For removing end of line comments, I added the following line: `gsub(/\s*#.*$/, "", $3); # Remove comments`, before the `printf`.

Comment: It also can't handle YAML arrays, which is covered in Martin Hecht's answer below.

Comment: I'd like to suggest treating the need to process YAML as a strong indication that a higher order programming language is more appropriate for the problem at hand.

Comment: Instead of `fs=$(echo @|tr @ '\034')` use `fs=$'\034'`.

Comment: I'm stuck with an edge case where I need to have variables prefixed with an '@' to also be parsed. I'm using it for a script that uses wp-cli.yml's syntax. In this file, variables prefix with an '@' are used to define aliases to different WordPress environments.

How would I add that functionality?

Comment: how can we assign each of the property to a variable ? and use it later in script

Answer (score 134):

I've written `shyaml` in python for YAML query needs from the shell command line.

Overview:

```
$ pip install shyaml      ## installation
```

Example's YAML file (with complex features):

```
$ cat <<EOF > test.yaml
name: "MyName !!"
subvalue:
    how-much: 1.1
    things:
        - first
        - second
        - third
    other-things: [a, b, c]
    maintainer: "Valentin Lab"
    description: |
        Multiline description:
        Line 1
        Line 2
EOF
```

Basic query:

```
$ cat test.yaml | shyaml get-value subvalue.maintainer
Valentin Lab
```

More complex looping query on complex values:

```
$ cat test.yaml | shyaml values-0 | \
  while read -r -d $'\0' value; do
      echo "RECEIVED: '$value'"
  done
RECEIVED: '1.1'
RECEIVED: '- first
- second
- third'
RECEIVED: '2'
RECEIVED: 'Valentin Lab'
RECEIVED: 'Multiline description:
Line 1
Line 2'
```

A few key points:

- all YAML types and syntax oddities are correctly handled, as multiline, quoted strings, inline sequences...
- `\0` padded output is available for solid multiline entry manipulation.
- simple dotted notation to select sub-values (ie: `subvalue.maintainer` is a valid key).
- access by index is provided to sequences (ie: `subvalue.things.-1` is the last element of the `subvalue.things` sequence.)
- access to all sequence/structs elements in one go for use in bash loops.
- you can output whole subpart of a YAML file as ... YAML, which blend well for further manipulations with shyaml.

More sample and documentation are available on the [shyaml github page](https://github.com/0k/shyaml) or the [shyaml PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/shyaml).

Comment: This is awesome! Would be great if there was a flag to ignore yaml values that are blank in the output. Right now it outputs "null". I'm using it along with envdir to output a docker-compose file to envdir `cat docker-compose.yml | shyaml get-value api.environment | grep -v null | awk -F': ' '{print $2 > ("envdir/" $1)}'`

Comment: @JiminyCricket Please use the github issue page ! I would be glad at least to keep track of this. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, `shyaml` is ridiculously slow

Comment: so cool. Thanks

Answer (score 113):

> [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) is a lightweight and portable command-line YAML processor

> The aim of the project is to be the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) or sed of yaml files.

(https://github.com/mikefarah/yq#readme)

As an example (stolen straight from the documentation), given a sample.yaml file of:

```
---
bob:
  item1:
    cats: bananas
  item2:
    cats: apples
```

then

```
yq eval '.bob.*.cats' sample.yaml
```

will output

```
- bananas
- apples
```

Comment: it is just lacking the filtering capabilities

Comment: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/yq has 26,679 install over the last year.

Comment: @Antonin I'm not sure if this is what you mean but it looks like it has some filtering capabilities now: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/path-expressions

Comment: Any idea how we use this inside the bash script? Like trying to set if as a var actually writes to the yaml file 

Answer (score 83):

Given that Python3 and PyYAML are quite easy dependencies to meet nowadays, the following may help:

```
yaml() {
    python3 -c "import yaml;print(yaml.safe_load(open('$1'))$2)"
}

VALUE=$(yaml ~/my_yaml_file.yaml "['a_key']")
```

Comment: I love shyaml, but on disconnected systems this is a life-saver. Should work with vast majority of python2 as well, e.g., RHEL.

Comment: Maybe use `yaml.safe_load` as it is safer. https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Comment: underrated answer

Comment: This is great. I made a tweaked version to print arrays as an item per line. `python3 -c "import yaml;f=yaml.safe_load(open('$1'))$2;print('\n'.join(str(i) for i in f) if type(f)==list else f);"`

Answer (score 38):

here an extended version of the Stefan Farestam's answer:

```
function parse_yaml {
   local prefix=$2
   local s='[[:space:]]*' w='[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' fs=$(echo @|tr @ '\034')
   sed -ne "s|,$s\]$s\$|]|" \
        -e ":1;s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\[$s\(.*\)$s,$s\(.*\)$s\]|\1\2: [\3]\n\1  - \4|;t1" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\[$s\(.*\)$s\]|\1\2:\n\1  - \3|;p" $1 | \
   sed -ne "s|,$s}$s\$|}|" \
        -e ":1;s|^\($s\)-$s{$s\(.*\)$s,$s\($w\)$s:$s\(.*\)$s}|\1- {\2}\n\1  \3: \4|;t1" \
        -e    "s|^\($s\)-$s{$s\(.*\)$s}|\1-\n\1  \2|;p" | \
   sed -ne "s|^\($s\):|\1|" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)-$s[\"']\(.*\)[\"']$s\$|\1$fs$fs\2|p" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)-$s\(.*\)$s\$|\1$fs$fs\2|p" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s[\"']\(.*\)[\"']$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\(.*\)$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" | \
   awk -F$fs '{
      indent = length($1)/2;
      vname[indent] = $2;
      for (i in vname) {if (i > indent) {delete vname[i]; idx[i]=0}}
      if(length($2)== 0){  vname[indent]= ++idx[indent] };
      if (length($3) > 0) {
         vn=""; for (i=0; i<indent; i++) { vn=(vn)(vname[i])("_")}
         printf("%s%s%s=\"%s\"\n", "'$prefix'",vn, vname[indent], $3);
      }
   }'
}
```

This version supports the `-` notation and the short notation for dictionaries and lists. The following input:

```
global:
  input:
    - "main.c"
    - "main.h"
  flags: [ "-O3", "-fpic" ]
  sample_input:
    -  { property1: value, property2: "value2" }
    -  { property1: "value3", property2: 'value 4' }
```

produces this output:

```
global_input_1="main.c"
global_input_2="main.h"
global_flags_1="-O3"
global_flags_2="-fpic"
global_sample_input_1_property1="value"
global_sample_input_1_property2="value2"
global_sample_input_2_property1="value3"
global_sample_input_2_property2="value 4"
```

as you can see the `-` items automatically get numbered in order to obtain different variable names for each item. In `bash` there are no multidimensional arrays, so this is one way to work around. Multiple levels are supported. 
To work around the problem with trailing white spaces mentioned by @briceburg one should enclose the values in single or double quotes. However, there are still some limitations: Expansion of the dictionaries and lists can produce wrong results when values contain commas. Also, more complex structures like values spanning multiple lines (like ssh-keys) are not (yet) supported.

A few words about the code: The first `sed` command expands the short form of dictionaries `{ key: value, ...}` to regular and converts them to more simple yaml style. The second `sed` call does the same for the short notation of lists and converts `[ entry, ... ]` to an itemized list with the `-` notation. The third `sed` call is the original one that handled normal dictionaries, now with the addition to handle lists with `-` and indentations. The `awk` part introduces an index for each indentation level and increases it when the variable name is empty (i.e. when processing a list). The current value of the counters are used instead of the empty vname. When going up one level, the counters are zeroed.

Edit: I have created a [github repository](https://github.com/mrbaseman/parse_yaml) for this.

Answer (score 35):

It's possible to pass a small script to some interpreters, like Python. An easy way to do so using Ruby and its YAML library is the following:

```
$ RUBY_SCRIPT="data = YAML::load(STDIN.read); puts data['a']; puts data['b']"
$ echo -e '---\na: 1234\nb: 4321' | ruby -ryaml -e "$RUBY_SCRIPT"
1234
4321
```

, where`data` is a hash (or array) with the values from yaml.

As a bonus, it'll parse [Jekyll's front matter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) just fine.

```
ruby -ryaml -e "puts YAML::load(open(ARGV.first).read)['tags']" example.md
```

Comment: is it usable? you have put yaml by echo to ruby interpreter. but how should be use this variable under rest of bash script?

Comment: Yes, it's usable. The `RUBY_SCRIPT` variable is a ruby script which may be written to a file instead (run with `ruby -ryaml <rubyscript_filename>`). It contains the logic to transform the input text into some output text, internally storing the content into the `data` variable. The echo outputs a yaml text, but you may use `cat <yaml_filename>` to pipe the content of a file instead.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see this in example above. At first variable RUBY_SCRIPT keeps code for ruby interpreter. Next echo -e simulates any yaml data, this is by pile redirected into ruby interpreter. This calls ruby code as inline script and finally print to output examples 'a' and 'b' variables. Then where is variable loading into bash for his rest executable code? I see only one workaround. putting ruby outout into temporary_file, that should conain lines: variable='value' , and after that load it into bash by '. temporary_file'. but this is workaround, not resolution.

Comment: @Znik once you've got something on the stdout, produced by something feeded with stdin, the rest relies in bash coder's hands (and as a reminder, if you need the ``stdout`` to be fed into variable, you don't have to rely on temporary files! use ``x=$(...)`` or even ``read a b c < <(...)``). So, this is a valid solution when you know exactly what you want to fetch in the YAML file and know how to write the ruby lines to access this data. Even if it is rough, it's a full proof of concept of the idea IMHO. It's true nonetheless that it doesn't provide you a full bash abstraction.

Comment: Yes it is. You're rigt. Thak you for that trick. Using one variable is simple. but many wariables aren't. trick with read variable list < <(execution to stdout) is very usefull :)

Comment: Best suggestion so far. I've adopted it and modified it slightly (to be parameterizable on bash level) and I'm happily using it. Thanks!

Comment: this is unbelievably brilliant

Answer (score 22):

Moving my answer from [How to convert a json response into yaml in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53315791/5291015), since this seems to be the authoritative post on dealing with YAML text parsing from command line.

I would like to add details about the `yq` YAML implementation. Since there are two implementations of this YAML parser lying around, both having the name `yq`, it is hard to differentiate which one is in use, without looking at the implementations' DSL. There two available implementations are

1. [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) - The more often talked about version, which is a wrapper over `jq`, written in Python using the PyYAML library for YAML parsing
2. [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) - A Go implementation, with its own dynamic DSL using the go-yaml v3 parser.

Both are available for installation via standard installation package managers on almost all major distributions

1. kislyuk/yq - [Installation instructions](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/#installation)
2. mikefarah/yq - [Installation instructions](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#install)

Both the versions have some pros and cons over the other, but a few valid points to highlight (adopted from their repo instructions)

**kislyuk/yq**

1. Since the DSL is the adopted completely from `jq`, for users familiar with the latter, the parsing and manipulation becomes quite straightforward
2. Supports mode to [preserve YAML tags and styles](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/#preserving-tags-and-styles-using-the-y-yaml-roundtrip-option), but loses comments during the conversion. Since `jq` [doesn't preserve comments](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq/issues/106), during the round-trip conversion, the comments are lost.
3. As part of the package, [XML support](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/#xml-support) is built in. An executable, `xq`, which transcodes XML to JSON using [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) and pipes it to `jq`, on which you can apply the same DSL to perform CRUD operations on the objects and round-trip the output back to XML.
4. Supports in-place edit mode with `-i` flag (similar to `sed -i`)

**mikefarah/yq**

1. Prone to frequent changes in DSL, [migration from 2.x - 3.x](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/upgrading-from-v2)
2. Rich support for anchors, styles and tags. But lookout for bugs once in a while
3. A relatively simple [Path expression](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/path-expressions) syntax to navigate and match yaml nodes
4. Supports YAML->JSON, JSON->YAML formatting and pretty printing YAML (with comments)
5. Supports in-place edit mode with `-i` flag (similar to `sed -i`)
6. Supports coloring the output YAML with `-C` flag (not applicable for JSON output) and indentation of the sub elements (default at 2 spaces)
7. Supports Shell completion for most shells - Bash, zsh (because of powerful support from [spf13/cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra#generating-shell-completions) used to generate CLI flags)

---

My take on the following YAML (referenced in other answer as well) with both the versions

```yaml
root_key1: this is value one
root_key2: "this is value two"

drink:
  state: liquid
  coffee:
    best_served: hot
    colour: brown
  orange_juice:
    best_served: cold
    colour: orange

food:
  state: solid
  apple_pie:
    best_served: warm

root_key_3: this is value three
```

Various actions to be performed with both the implementations (some frequently used operations)

1. Modifying node value at root level -  Change value of `root_key2`
2. Modifying array contents, adding value  - Add property to `coffee`
3. Modifying array contents, deleting value - Delete property from `orange_juice`
4. Printing key/value pairs with paths - For all items under `food`

**Using kislyuk/yq**

1. ```
   yq -y '.root_key2 |= "this is a new value"' yaml
   ```
2. ```
   yq -y '.drink.coffee += { time: "always"}' yaml
   ```
3. ```
   yq -y 'del(.drink.orange_juice.colour)' yaml
   ```
4. ```
   yq -r '.food|paths(scalars) as $p | [($p|join(".")), (getpath($p)|tojson)] | @tsv' yaml
   ```

Which is pretty straightforward. All you need is to transcode `jq` JSON output back into YAML with the `-y` flag.

**Using mikefarah/yq**

1. ```
    yq w yaml root_key2 "this is a new value"
   ```
2. ```
    yq w yaml drink.coffee.time "always"
   ```
3. ```
    yq d yaml drink.orange_juice.colour
   ```
4. ```
    yq r yaml --printMode pv "food.**"
   ```

---

As of today Dec 21st 2020, `yq` v4 is in beta and supports much powerful path expressions and supports DSL similar to using `jq`. Read the transition notes - [Upgrading from V3](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/upgrading-from-v3)

Answer (score 14):

I just wrote a parser that I called *Yay!* (*Yaml ain't Yamlesque!*) which parses *Yamlesque*, a small subset of YAML. So, if you're looking for a 100% compliant YAML parser for Bash then this isn't it. However, to quote the OP, if you want *a structured configuration file which is as easy as possible for a non-technical user to edit* that is YAML-like, this may be of interest.

It's [inspred by the earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21189044) but writes associative arrays (**yes, it requires Bash 4.x**) instead of basic variables. It does so in a way that allows the data to be parsed without prior knowledge of the keys so that  data-driven code can be written.

As well as the key/value array elements, each array has a `keys` array containing a list of key names, a `children` array containing names of child arrays and a `parent` key that refers to its parent.

[This](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnlane/random-toolbox/master/examples/example.yay) is an example of Yamlesque:

```
root_key1: this is value one
root_key2: "this is value two"

drink:
  state: liquid
  coffee:
    best_served: hot
    colour: brown
  orange_juice:
    best_served: cold
    colour: orange

food:
  state: solid
  apple_pie:
    best_served: warm

root_key_3: this is value three
```

[Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnlane/random-toolbox/master/examples/yay_example) is an example showing how to use it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# An example showing how to use Yay

. /usr/lib/yay

# helper to get array value at key
value() { eval echo \${$1[$2]}; }

# print a data collection
print_collection() {
  for k in $(value $1 keys)
  do
    echo "$2$k = $(value $1 $k)"
  done

  for c in $(value $1 children)
  do
    echo -e "$2$c\n$2{"
    print_collection $c "  $2"
    echo "$2}"
  done
}

yay example
print_collection example
```

which outputs:

```
root_key1 = this is value one
root_key2 = this is value two
root_key_3 = this is value three
example_drink
{
  state = liquid
  example_coffee
  {
    best_served = hot
    colour = brown
  }
  example_orange_juice
  {
    best_served = cold
    colour = orange
  }
}
example_food
{
  state = solid
  example_apple_pie
  {
    best_served = warm
  }
}
```

And [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnlane/random-toolbox/master/usr/lib/yay) is the parser:

```
yay_parse() {

   # find input file
   for f in "$1" "$1.yay" "$1.yml"
   do
     [[ -f "$f" ]] && input="$f" && break
   done
   [[ -z "$input" ]] && exit 1

   # use given dataset prefix or imply from file name
   [[ -n "$2" ]] && local prefix="$2" || {
     local prefix=$(basename "$input"); prefix=${prefix%.*}
   }

   echo "declare -g -A $prefix;"

   local s='[[:space:]]*' w='[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' fs=$(echo @|tr @ '\034')
   sed -n -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\"\(.*\)\"$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" \
          -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\(.*\)$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" "$input" |
   awk -F$fs '{
      indent       = length($1)/2;
      key          = $2;
      value        = $3;

      # No prefix or parent for the top level (indent zero)
      root_prefix  = "'$prefix'_";
      if (indent ==0 ) {
        prefix = "";          parent_key = "'$prefix'";
      } else {
        prefix = root_prefix; parent_key = keys[indent-1];
      }

      keys[indent] = key;

      # remove keys left behind if prior row was indented more than this row
      for (i in keys) {if (i > indent) {delete keys[i]}}

      if (length(value) > 0) {
         # value
         printf("%s%s[%s]=\"%s\";\n", prefix, parent_key , key, value);
         printf("%s%s[keys]+=\" %s\";\n", prefix, parent_key , key);
      } else {
         # collection
         printf("%s%s[children]+=\" %s%s\";\n", prefix, parent_key , root_prefix, key);
         printf("declare -g -A %s%s;\n", root_prefix, key);
         printf("%s%s[parent]=\"%s%s\";\n", root_prefix, key, prefix, parent_key);
      }
   }'
}

# helper to load yay data file
yay() { eval $(yay_parse "$@"); }
```

There is some documentation in the linked source file and below is a short explanation of what the code does.

The `yay_parse` function first locates the `input` file or exits with an exit status of 1. Next, it determines the dataset `prefix`, either explicitly specified or derived from the file name.

It writes valid `bash` commands to its standard output that, if executed, define arrays representing the contents of the input data file. The first of these defines the top-level array:

```
echo "declare -g -A $prefix;"
```

Note that array declarations are associative (`-A`) which is a feature of Bash version 4. Declarations are also global (`-g`) so they can be executed in a function but be available to the global scope like the `yay` helper:

```
yay() { eval $(yay_parse "$@"); }
```

The input data is initially processed with `sed`. It drops lines that don't match the Yamlesque format specification before delimiting the valid Yamlesque fields with an ASCII [File Separator](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/file-separator-ascii-code-28.html) character and removing any double-quotes surrounding the value field.

```
 local s='[[:space:]]*' w='[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' fs=$(echo @|tr @ '\034')
 sed -n -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\"\(.*\)\"$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\(.*\)$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" "$input" |
```

The two expressions are similar; they differ only because the first one picks out quoted values where as the second one picks out unquoted ones.

The [File Separator](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/file-separator-ascii-code-28.html) (28/hex 12/octal 034) is used because, as a non-printable character, it is unlikely to be in the input data.

The result is piped into `awk` which processes its input one line at a time. It uses the [FS](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/file-separator-ascii-code-28.html) character to assign each field to a variable:

```
indent       = length($1)/2;
key          = $2;
value        = $3;
```

All lines have an indent (possibly zero) and a key but they don't all have a value. It computes an indent level for the line dividing the length of the first field, which contains the leading whitespace, by two. The top level items without any indent are at indent level zero.

Next, it works out what `prefix` to use for the current item. This is what gets added to a key name to make an array name. There's a `root_prefix` for the top-level array which is defined as the data set name and an underscore:

```
root_prefix  = "'$prefix'_";
if (indent ==0 ) {
  prefix = "";          parent_key = "'$prefix'";
} else {
  prefix = root_prefix; parent_key = keys[indent-1];
}
```

The `parent_key` is the key at the indent level above the current line's indent level and represents the collection that the current line is part of. The collection's key/value pairs will be stored in an array with its name defined as the concatenation of the `prefix` and `parent_key`.

For the top level (indent level zero) the data set prefix is used as the parent key so it has no prefix (it's set to `""`). All other arrays are prefixed with the root prefix.

Next, the current key is inserted into an (awk-internal) array containing the keys. This array persists throughout the whole awk session and therefore contains keys inserted by prior lines. The key is inserted into the array using its indent as the array index.

```
keys[indent] = key;
```

Because this array contains keys from previous lines, any keys with an indent level grater than the current line's indent level are removed:

```
 for (i in keys) {if (i > indent) {delete keys[i]}}
```

This leaves the keys array containing the key-chain from the root at indent level 0 to the current line. It removes stale keys that remain when the prior line was indented deeper than the current line.

The final section outputs the `bash` commands: an input line without a value starts a new indent level (a *collection* in YAML parlance) and an input line with a value adds a key to the current collection.

The collection's name is the concatenation of the current line's `prefix` and `parent_key`.

When a key has a value, a key with that value is assigned to the current collection like this:

```
printf("%s%s[%s]=\"%s\";\n", prefix, parent_key , key, value);
printf("%s%s[keys]+=\" %s\";\n", prefix, parent_key , key);
```

The first statement outputs the command to assign the value to an associative array element named after the key and the second one outputs the command to add the key to the collection's space-delimited `keys` list:

```
<current_collection>[<key>]="<value>";
<current_collection>[keys]+=" <key>";
```

When a key doesn't have a value, a new collection is started like this:

```
printf("%s%s[children]+=\" %s%s\";\n", prefix, parent_key , root_prefix, key);
printf("declare -g -A %s%s;\n", root_prefix, key);
```

The first statement outputs the command to add the new collection to the current's collection's space-delimited `children` list and the second one outputs the command to declare a new associative array for the new collection:

```
<current_collection>[children]+=" <new_collection>"
declare -g -A <new_collection>;
```

All of the output from `yay_parse` can be parsed as bash commands by the bash `eval` or `source` built-in commands.

Comment: Have you considered making this a project on GitHub? Or is it already?

Comment: @daniel, it is in GitHub but not in its own repo - you can find it in [here](https://github.com/johnlane/random-toolbox). See the `examples` and `usr/lib` directories, These are linked in my answer to the question. If there's interest I could break it out into its own repo.

Comment: Kudos on YAY.  At first, I rewrote it to be pure bash, but then I couldn't stop myself and reimplemented it as a basic parser with support for arrays and nested structures that can't step on each others' names.  It's at https://github.com/binaryphile/y2s.

Answer (score 12):

Hard to say because it depends on what you want the parser to extract from your YAML document. For simple cases, you might be able to use `grep`, `cut`, `awk` etc. For more complex parsing you would need to use a full-blown parsing library such as Python's [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML) or [YAML::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/YAML-Perl-0.02/lib/YAML/Perl.pod).

Answer (score 7):

I used to convert yaml to json using python and do my processing in jq.

```
python -c "import yaml; import json; from pathlib import Path; print(json.dumps(yaml.safe_load(Path('file.yml').read_text())))" | jq '.'
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to convert the YAML to JSON, then use jq to interact with the JSON representation either to extract information from it or edit it.

I wrote a simple bash script that contains this glue - see [Y2J project on GitHub](https://github.com/wildducktheories/y2j)

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -ne 'chomp; printf qq/%s="%s"\n/, split(/\s*:\s*/,$_,2)' file.yml > file.sh
```

Comment: usefull only for flat configurations. it is not applicable for structured yaml. another, how to prevent using temporary file.sh ?

Answer (score 3):

If you need a single value you could a tool which converts your YAML document to JSON and feed to [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq), for example [`yq`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq).

Content of sample.yaml:

```
---
bob:
  item1:
    cats: bananas
  item2:
    cats: apples
  thing:
    cats: oranges
```

Example:

```
$ yq -r '.bob["thing"]["cats"]' sample.yaml 
oranges
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very specific, but I think my answer could be helpful for certain users.
If you have `node` and `npm` installed on your machine, you can use `js-yaml`.
First install :

```
npm i -g js-yaml
# or locally
npm i js-yaml
```

then in your bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
js-yaml your-yaml-file.yml
```

Also if you are using `jq` you can do something like that

```
#!/bin/bash
json="$(js-yaml your-yaml-file.yml)"
aproperty="$(jq '.apropery' <<< "$json")"
echo "$aproperty"
```

Because `js-yaml` converts a yaml file to a json string literal. You can then use the string with any json parser in your unix system.

Answer (score 2):

**A quick way to do the thing now** (previous ones haven't worked for me):

```
sudo wget https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/download/v4.4.1/yq_linux_amd64 -O /usr/bin/yq &&\
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/yq
```

**Example asd.yaml:**

```
a_list:
  - key1: value1
    key2: value2
    key3: value3
```

**parsing root:**

```
user@vm:~$ yq e '.' asd.yaml                                                                                                         
a_list:
  - key1: value1
    key2: value2
    key3: value3
```

**parsing key3:**

```
user@vm:~$ yq e '.a_list[0].key3' asd.yaml                                                                                             
value3
```

Comment: there are 2 answers about `yq` already...

Answer (score 1):

If you have python 2 and PyYAML, you can use this parser I wrote called [parse_yaml.py](https://github.com/cangers/misc). Some of the neater things it does is let you choose a prefix (in case you have more than one file with similar variables) and to pick a single value from a yaml file.

For example if you have these yaml files:

staging.yaml:

```
db:
    type: sqllite
    host: 127.0.0.1
    user: dev
    password: password123
```

prod.yaml:

```
db:
    type: postgres
    host: 10.0.50.100
    user: postgres
    password: password123
```

You can load both without conflict.

```
$ eval $(python parse_yaml.py prod.yaml --prefix prod --cap)
$ eval $(python parse_yaml.py staging.yaml --prefix stg --cap)
$ echo $PROD_DB_HOST
10.0.50.100
$ echo $STG_DB_HOST
127.0.0.1
```

And even cherry pick the values you want.

```
$ prod_user=$(python parse_yaml.py prod.yaml --get db_user)
$ prod_port=$(python parse_yaml.py prod.yaml --get db_port --default 5432)
$ echo prod_user
postgres
$ echo prod_port
5432
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [equivalent](https://github.com/030/go-yq) of [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) that is written in golang:

```
./go-yg -yamlFile /home/user/dev/ansible-firefox/defaults/main.yml -key
firefox_version
```

returns:

```
62.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need a solution for "How to work with YAML/JSON/compatible data from a shell script" which works on just about every OS with Python (*nix, OSX, Windows), consider [yamlpath](https://github.com/wwkimball/yamlpath), which provides several command-line tools for reading, writing, searching, and merging YAML, EYAML, JSON, and compatible files.  Since just about every OS either comes with Python pre-installed or it is trivial to install, this makes yamlpath highly portable.  Even more interesting:  this project defines an intuitive path language with very powerful, command-line-friendly syntax that enables accessing one *or more* nodes.

To your specific question and after installing yamlpath using [Python's native package manager](https://github.com/wwkimball/yamlpath#installing) or your OS's package manager (yamlpath is available via RPM to some OSes):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Read values directly from YAML (or EYAML, JSON, etc) for use in this shell script:
myShellVar=$(yaml-get --query=any.path.no[matter%how].complex source-file.yaml)

# Use the value any way you need:
echo "Retrieved ${myShellVar}"

# Perhaps change the value and write it back:
myShellVar="New Value"
yaml-set --change=/any/path/no[matter%how]/complex --value="$myShellVar" source-file.yaml
```

You didn't specify that the data was a simple Scalar value though, so let's up the ante.  What if the result you want is an Array?  Even more challenging, what if it's an Array-of-Hashes and you only want one property of each result?  Suppose further that your data is actually spread out across *multiple* YAML files and you need all the results in a single query.  That's a much more interesting question to demonstrate with.  So, suppose you have these two YAML files:

File: **data1.yaml**

```yaml
---
baubles:
  - name: Doohickey
    sku: 0-000-1
    price: 4.75
    weight: 2.7g
  - name: Doodad
    sku: 0-000-2
    price: 10.5
    weight: 5g
  - name: Oddball
    sku: 0-000-3
    price: 25.99
    weight: 25kg
```

File:  **data2.yaml**

```yaml
---
baubles:
  - name: Fob
    sku: 0-000-4
    price: 0.99
    weight: 18mg
  - name: Doohickey
    price: 10.5
  - name: Oddball
    sku: 0-000-3
    description: This ball is odd
```

How would you report only the `sku` of every item in inventory after applying the changes from data2.yaml to data1.yaml, all from a shell script?  Try this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
baubleSKUs=($(yaml-merge --aoh=deep data1.yaml data2.yaml | yaml-get --query=/baubles/sku -))

for sku in "${baubleSKUs[@]}"; do
    echo "Found bauble SKU:  ${sku}"
done
```

You get exactly what you need from only a few lines of code:

```
Found bauble SKU:  0-000-1
Found bauble SKU:  0-000-2
Found bauble SKU:  0-000-3
Found bauble SKU:  0-000-4
```

As you can see, yamlpath turns very complex problems into trivial solutions.  Note that the entire query was handled as a stream; no YAML files were changed by the query and there were no temp files.

I realize this is "yet another tool to solve the same question" but after reading the other answers here, yamlpath appears more portable and robust than most alternatives.  It also fully understands YAML/JSON/compatible files and it does *not* need to convert YAML to JSON to perform requested operations.  As such, comments within the original YAML file are preserved whenever you need to change data in the source YAML file.  Like some alternatives, yamlpath is also portable across OSes.  More importantly, yamlpath defines a query language that is extremely powerful, enabling very specialized/filtered data queries.  It can even operate against results from disparate parts of the file in a single query.

If you want to get or set many values in the data at once -- including complex data like hashes/arrays/maps/lists -- yamlpath can do that.  Want a value but don't know precisely where it is in the document?  yamlpath can find it and give you the exact path(s).  Need to merge multiple data file together, including from STDIN?  yamlpath does that, too.  Further, yamlpath fully comprehends YAML anchors and their aliases, always giving or changing exactly the data you expect whether it is a concrete or referenced value.

Disclaimer:  I wrote and maintain yamlpath, which is based on ruamel.yaml, which is in turn based on PyYAML.  As such, yamlpath is fully standards-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Complex parsing is easiest with a library such as Python's [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML) or [YAML::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eingy/YAML-Perl-0.02/lib/YAML/Perl.pod).

If you want to parse all the YAML values into bash values, try this script. This will handle comments as well. See example usage below:

```
# pparse.py

import yaml
import sys
            
def parse_yaml(yml, name=''):
    if isinstance(yml, list):
        for data in yml:
            parse_yaml(data, name)
    elif isinstance(yml, dict):
        if (len(yml) == 1) and not isinstance(yml[list(yml.keys())[0]], list):
            print(str(name+'_'+list(yml.keys())[0]+'='+str(yml[list(yml.keys())[0]]))[1:])
        else:
            for key in yml:
                parse_yaml(yml[key], name+'_'+key)

            
if __name__=="__main__":
    yml = yaml.safe_load(open(sys.argv[1]))
    parse_yaml(yml)
```

test.yml

```
- folders:
  - temp_folder: datasets/outputs/tmp
  - keep_temp_folder: false

- MFA:
  - MFA: false
  - speaker_count: 1
  - G2P: 
    - G2P: true
    - G2P_model: models/MFA/G2P/english_g2p.zip
    - input_folder: datasets/outputs/Youtube/ljspeech/wavs
    - output_dictionary: datasets/outputs/Youtube/ljspeech/dictionary.dict
  - dictionary: datasets/outputs/Youtube/ljspeech/dictionary.dict
  - acoustic_model: models/MFA/acoustic/english.zip
  - temp_folder: datasets/outputs/tmp
  - jobs: 4
  - align:
    - config: configs/MFA/align.yaml
    - dataset: datasets/outputs/Youtube/ljspeech/wavs
    - output_folder: datasets/outputs/Youtube/ljspeech-aligned

- TTS:
  - output_folder: datasets/outputs/Youtube
  - preprocess:
    - preprocess: true
    - config: configs/TTS_preprocess.yaml # Default Config 
    - textgrid_folder: datasets/outputs/Youtube/ljspeech-aligned
    - output_duration_folder: datasets/outputs/Youtube/durations
    - sampling_rate: 44000 # Make sure sampling rate is same here as in preprocess config
```

Script where YAML values are needed:

```
yaml() {
    eval $(python pparse.py "$1")
}

yaml "test.yml"

# What python printed to bash:

folders_temp_folder=datasets/outputs/tmp
folders_keep_temp_folder=False
MFA_MFA=False
MFA_speaker_count=1
MFA_G2P_G2P=True
MFA_G2P_G2P_model=models/MFA/G2P/english_g2p.zip
MFA_G2P_input_folder=datasets/outputs/Youtube/ljspeech/wavs
MFA_G2P_output_dictionary=datasets/outputs/Youtube/ljspeech/dictionary.dict
MFA_dictionary=datasets/outputs/Youtube/ljspeech/dictionary.dict
MFA_acoustic_model=models/MFA/acoustic/english.zip
MFA_temp_folder=datasets/outputs/tmp
MFA_jobs=4
MFA_align_config=configs/MFA/align.yaml
MFA_align_dataset=datasets/outputs/Youtube/ljspeech/wavs
MFA_align_output_folder=datasets/outputs/Youtube/ljspeech-aligned
TTS_output_folder=datasets/outputs/Youtube
TTS_preprocess_preprocess=True
TTS_preprocess_config=configs/TTS_preprocess.yaml
TTS_preprocess_textgrid_folder=datasets/outputs/Youtube/ljspeech-aligned
TTS_preprocess_output_duration_folder=datasets/outputs/Youtube/durations
TTS_preprocess_sampling_rate=44000
```

Access variables with bash:

```
echo "$TTS_preprocess_sampling_rate";
>>> 44000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know what tags you are interested in and the yaml structure you expect then it is not that hard to write a simple YAML parser in Bash.

In the following example the parser reads a structured YAML file into environment variables, an array and an associative array.

Note: The complexity of this parser is tied to the structure of the YAML file.  You will need a separate subroutine for each structured component of the YAML file.  Highly structured YAML files might require a more sophisticated approach, eg a generic recursive descent parser.

The xmas.yaml file:

```
# Xmas YAML example
---
 # Values
 pear-tree: partridge
 turtle-doves: 2.718
 french-hens: 3

 # Array
 calling-birds:
   - huey
   - dewey
   - louie
   - fred

 # Structure
 xmas-fifth-day:
   calling-birds: four
   french-hens: 3
   golden-rings: 5
   partridges:
     count: 1
     location: "a pear tree"
   turtle-doves: two
```

The parser uses `mapfile` to read the file into memory as an array then cycles through each tag and creates environment variables.

- `pear-tree:`, `turtle-doves:` and `french-hens:` end up as simple environment variables
- `calling-birds:` becomes an array
- The `xmas-fifth-day:` structure is represented as an associative array however you could encode these as environment variables if you are not using Bash 4.0 or later.
- Comments and white space are ignored.

```
#!/bin/bash
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# A simple parser for the xmas.yaml file
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# 
# xmas.yaml tags
#  #                        - Ignored
#                           - Blank lines are ignored
#  ---                      - Initialiser for days-of-xmas 
#   pear-tree: partridge    - a string
#   turtle-doves: 2.718     - a string, no float type in Bash
#   french-hens: 3          - a number
#   calling-birds:          - an array of strings
#     - huey                - calling-birds[0]
#     - dewey
#     - louie
#     - fred
#   xmas-fifth-day:         - an associative array
#     calling-birds: four   - a string
#     french-hens: 3        - a number
#     golden-rings: 5       - a number
#     partridges:           - changes the key to partridges.xxx
#       count: 1            - a number
#       location: "a pear tree" - a string
#     turtle-doves: two     - a string
# 
# This requires the following routines
# ParseXMAS
#   parses #, ---, blank line
#   unexpected tag error
#   calls days-of-xmas
#
# days-of-xmas
#   parses pear-tree, turtle-doves, french-hens
#   calls calling-birds
#   calls xmas-fifth-day
# 
# calling-birds
#   elements of the array
#
# xmas-fifth-day
#   parses calling-birds, french-hens, golden-rings, turtle-doves
#   calls partridges
# 
# partridges
#   parses partridges.count, partridges.location
#

function ParseXMAS()
{

  # days-of-xmas
  #   parses pear-tree, turtle-doves, french-hens
  #   calls calling-birds
  #   calls xmas-fifth-day
  # 
  function days-of-xmas()
  {
    unset PearTree TurtleDoves FrenchHens

    while [ $CURRENT_ROW -lt $ROWS ]
    do
      LINE=( ${CONFIG[${CURRENT_ROW}]} )
      TAG=${LINE[0]}
      unset LINE[0]

      VALUE="${LINE[*]}"

      echo "  days-of-xmas[${CURRENT_ROW}] ${TAG}=${VALUE}"

      if [ "$TAG" = "pear-tree:" ]
      then
        declare -g PearTree=$VALUE
      elif [ "$TAG" = "turtle-doves:" ]
      then
        declare -g TurtleDoves=$VALUE
      elif [ "$TAG" = "french-hens:" ]
      then
        declare -g FrenchHens=$VALUE
      elif [ "$TAG" = "calling-birds:" ]
      then
        let CURRENT_ROW=$(($CURRENT_ROW + 1))
        calling-birds
        continue
      elif [ "$TAG" = "xmas-fifth-day:" ]
      then
        let CURRENT_ROW=$(($CURRENT_ROW + 1))
        xmas-fifth-day
        continue
      elif [ -z "$TAG" ] || [ "$TAG" = "#" ]
      then
        # Ignore comments and blank lines
        true
      else
        # time to bug out
        break
      fi

      let CURRENT_ROW=$(($CURRENT_ROW + 1))
    done
  }

  # calling-birds
  #   elements of the array
  function calling-birds()
  {
    unset CallingBirds

    declare -ag CallingBirds

    while [ $CURRENT_ROW -lt $ROWS ]
    do
      LINE=( ${CONFIG[${CURRENT_ROW}]} )
      TAG=${LINE[0]}
      unset LINE[0]

      VALUE="${LINE[*]}"

      echo "    calling-birds[${CURRENT_ROW}] ${TAG}=${VALUE}"

      if [ "$TAG" = "-" ]
      then
        CallingBirds[${#CallingBirds[*]}]=$VALUE
      elif [ -z "$TAG" ] || [ "$TAG" = "#" ]
      then
        # Ignore comments and blank lines
        true
      else
        # time to bug out
        break
      fi

      let CURRENT_ROW=$(($CURRENT_ROW + 1))
    done
  }

  # xmas-fifth-day
  #   parses calling-birds, french-hens, golden-rings, turtle-doves
  #   calls fifth-day-partridges
  # 
  function xmas-fifth-day()
  {
    unset XmasFifthDay

    declare -Ag XmasFifthDay

    while [ $CURRENT_ROW -lt $ROWS ]
    do
      LINE=( ${CONFIG[${CURRENT_ROW}]} )
      TAG=${LINE[0]}
      unset LINE[0]

      VALUE="${LINE[*]}"

      echo "    xmas-fifth-day[${CURRENT_ROW}] ${TAG}=${VALUE}"

      if [ "$TAG" = "calling-birds:" ]
      then
        XmasFifthDay[CallingBirds]=$VALUE
      elif [ "$TAG" = "french-hens:" ]
      then
        XmasFifthDay[FrenchHens]=$VALUE
      elif [ "$TAG" = "golden-rings:" ]
      then
        XmasFifthDay[GOLDEN-RINGS]=$VALUE
      elif [ "$TAG" = "turtle-doves:" ]
      then
        XmasFifthDay[TurtleDoves]=$VALUE
      elif [ "$TAG" = "partridges:" ]
      then
        let CURRENT_ROW=$(($CURRENT_ROW + 1))
        partridges
        continue
      elif [ -z "$TAG" ] || [ "$TAG" = "#" ]
      then
        # Ignore comments and blank lines
        true
      else
        # time to bug out
        break
      fi
 
      let CURRENT_ROW=$(($CURRENT_ROW + 1))
    done
  }

  function partridges()
  {
    while [ $CURRENT_ROW -lt $ROWS ]
    do
      LINE=( ${CONFIG[${CURRENT_ROW}]} )
      TAG=${LINE[0]}
      unset LINE[0]

      VALUE="${LINE[*]}"

      echo "      partridges[${CURRENT_ROW}] ${TAG}=${VALUE}"

      if [ "$TAG" = "count:" ]
      then
        XmasFifthDay[PARTRIDGES.COUNT]=$VALUE
      elif [ "$TAG" = "location:" ]
      then
        XmasFifthDay[PARTRIDGES.LOCATION]=$VALUE
      elif [ -z "$TAG" ] || [ "$TAG" = "#" ]
      then
        # Ignore comments and blank lines
        true
      else
        # time to bug out
        break
      fi
 
      let CURRENT_ROW=$(($CURRENT_ROW + 1))
    done
  }

  # ===================================================================
  # Load the configuration file

  mapfile CONFIG < xmas.yaml

  let ROWS=${#CONFIG[@]}
  let CURRENT_ROW=0

  # +
  # #
  #
  # ---
  # -
  while [ $CURRENT_ROW -lt $ROWS ]
  do
    LINE=( ${CONFIG[${CURRENT_ROW}]} )
    TAG=${LINE[0]}
    unset LINE[0]

    VALUE="${LINE[*]}"

    echo "[${CURRENT_ROW}] ${TAG}=${VALUE}"

    if [ "$TAG" = "---" ]
    then
        let CURRENT_ROW=$(($CURRENT_ROW + 1))
        days-of-xmas
        continue
    elif [ -z "$TAG" ] || [ "$TAG" = "#" ]
    then
        # Ignore comments and blank lines
        true
    else
        echo "Unexpected tag at line $(($CURRENT_ROW + 1)): <${TAG}>={${VALUE}}"
        break
    fi

    let CURRENT_ROW=$(($CURRENT_ROW + 1))
  done
}

echo =========================================
ParseXMAS

echo =========================================
declare -p PearTree
declare -p TurtleDoves
declare -p FrenchHens
declare -p CallingBirds
declare -p XmasFifthDay
```

This produces the following output

```
=========================================
[0] #=Xmas YAML example
[1] ---=
  days-of-xmas[2] #=Values
  days-of-xmas[3] pear-tree:=partridge
  days-of-xmas[4] turtle-doves:=2.718
  days-of-xmas[5] french-hens:=3
  days-of-xmas[6] =
  days-of-xmas[7] #=Array
  days-of-xmas[8] calling-birds:=
    calling-birds[9] -=huey
    calling-birds[10] -=dewey
    calling-birds[11] -=louie
    calling-birds[12] -=fred
    calling-birds[13] =
    calling-birds[14] #=Structure
    calling-birds[15] xmas-fifth-day:=
  days-of-xmas[15] xmas-fifth-day:=
    xmas-fifth-day[16] calling-birds:=four
    xmas-fifth-day[17] french-hens:=3
    xmas-fifth-day[18] golden-rings:=5
    xmas-fifth-day[19] partridges:=
      partridges[20] count:=1
      partridges[21] location:="a pear tree"
      partridges[22] turtle-doves:=two
    xmas-fifth-day[22] turtle-doves:=two
=========================================
declare -- PearTree="partridge"
declare -- TurtleDoves="2.718"
declare -- FrenchHens="3"
declare -a CallingBirds=([0]="huey" [1]="dewey" [2]="louie" [3]="fred")
declare -A XmasFifthDay=([CallingBirds]="four" [PARTRIDGES.LOCATION]="\"a pear tree\"" [FrenchHens]="3" [GOLDEN-RINGS]="5" [PARTRIDGES.COUNT]="1" [TurtleDoves]="two" )
```

Answer (score 1):

In RHEL, this command outputs if STDIN is a YAML or die if not.

```
 yum install perl-YAML.noarch
 (...)
 cat someflux \
 | perl -MYAML -MData::Dumper \
        -e 'print Dumper YAML::Load(join q{}, <STDIN>)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) (The JavaScript Task Runner). Can be easily integrated with shell. It supports reading YAML (`grunt.file.readYAML`) and JSON (`grunt.file.readJSON`) files.

This can be achieved by creating a task in `Gruntfile.js` (or `Gruntfile.coffee`), e.g.:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.registerTask('foo', ['load_yml']);

    grunt.registerTask('load_yml', function () {
        var data = grunt.file.readYAML('foo.yml');
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function (g) {
          // ... switch (g) { case 'my_key':
        });
    });

};
```

then from shell just simply run `grunt foo` (check `grunt --help` for available tasks).

Further more you can implement `exec:foo` tasks (`grunt-exec`) with input variables passed from your task (`foo: { cmd: 'echo bar <%= foo %>' }`) in order to print the output in whatever format you want, then pipe it into another command.

---

There is also similar tool to Grunt, it's called [gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp) with additional plugin [gulp-yaml](https://github.com/crissdev/gulp-yaml).

Install via: `npm install --save-dev gulp-yaml`

Sample usage:

```
var yaml = require('gulp-yaml');

gulp.src('./src/*.yml')
  .pipe(yaml())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))

gulp.src('./src/*.yml')
  .pipe(yaml({ space: 2 }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))

gulp.src('./src/*.yml')
  .pipe(yaml({ safe: true }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
```

---

To more options to deal with [YAML format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), check [YAML site](http://www.yaml.org/) for available projects, libraries and other resources which can help you to parse that format.

---

Other tools:

- [Jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/)

  > parses, reads and creates JSON

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Torsten's answer:

```
export YML_PATH=./config.yml
yml() { # requires python modules yaml and munch installed
    python -c "import yaml; import munch; print(munch.munchify(yaml.safe_load(open('$YML_PATH'))).$1)"
}
PGPASSWORD=$(yml db.password) psql -h $(yml db.host) -p $(yml db.port) -d $(yml db.name) -U $(yml db.user) -f so_much_ugliness.sql
```

You can gently slap yourself if you use this (as I did) ;).

Answer (score -1):

I know my answer is specific, but if one already has **PHP** and **Symfony** installed, it can be very handy to use Symfony's YAML parser.

For instance:

```sh
php -r "require '$SYMFONY_ROOT_PATH/vendor/autoload.php'; \
    var_dump(\Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('$YAML_FILE_PATH')));"
```

Here I simply used `var_dump` to output the parsed array but of course you can do much more... :)