# YAML parser from bash

Tags: git, automation, symfony, parsing, yaml

I am developing a pre-prod server for a Symfony2 app

I made a little hook script to update all of my git repositories which contain a Symfony app.

```
# ...

# Save old database
DATABASE_NAME=`YAML Parser Command` 'app/config/parameters.yml' database_name
TODAY=`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"`
logger -t "Update website Symfony2" "Save SQL in $TODAY.sql"
mysqldump $DATABASE_NAME > sqlSave/$TODAY.sql 2>&1 | logger -t "Update website Symfony2"
# Update database with doctrine
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force  2>&1 | logger -t "Update website Symfony2"

# ...
```

How can I have access to the database name on this script ?

My server is on Debian. Is there a package to parse YAML?

Comment: Would you be alright with adding a dependency on a scripting language?  Many of them have YAML parsing libraries so you could call one of them and have it output the data you want from YAML.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse yaml/json file directly in your shell/bash with [niet](https://pypi.org/project/niet/).

Easy to install and easy to use:

```
$ pip install -U niet
```

Consider the following example:

```
$ cat dump.yaml
foo:
  bar:
    key: value
  baz:
    key: value
  tags:
    - one
    - two
```

You can parse this example file like this:

```
  $ niet dump.yaml foo.bar.key
  value
  $ for el in $(niet dump.yaml foo.tags); do echo ${el}; done
  one
  two
```

Niet have a good integration with shell and others bash like.

[Niet yaml parser documentation, source code, and samples](https://github.com/gr0und-s3ct0r/niet/).

Comment: i couldnt find `yq` for centos and your suggestion about `niet` really helped.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the structure of your `app/config/parameters.yml` and the location of `database_name` within it, you might be able to use [this parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31705244). It will parse

```
foo:
  bar:
    key: value
  baz:
    key: value
```

into bash associative arrays. 100% Bash, but it needs to be Bash 4.x. If you can't stick to Bash 4.x then there are other answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014632/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-from-a-linux-shell-script) that may help you.