# iterate through yaml using shell

Tags: bash, shell, loops, yaml

I have a config_file.yml file as:

```
sample:
    sql: "select * from dbname.tableName where sampleDate>='2018-07-20';"
    config: {'hosts': [!!python/tuple ['192.162.0.10', 3001]]}

sample2:
    sql: "select * from dbname.tableName where sampleDate<='2016-05-25';"
    config: {'hosts': [!!python/tuple ['190.160.0.10', 3002]]}
```

I want to iterate through its key value pairs till EOF using shell script. Basically I want to be able to iterate through each sql till EOF, and execute each sql in a shell loop.

Tried looking through a lot of docs but they dnt have enough info how to loop through yaml using shell.

Any ideas or example will be very helpful...

Thanks!

EDIT:

I am already using ->

```
parse_yaml() {
local prefix=$2
local s='[[:space:]]*' w='[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' fs=$(echo @|tr @ '\034')
sed -ne "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\"\(.*\)\"$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\(.*\)$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" $1 |
awk -F$fs '{
  indent = length($1)/2;
  vname[indent] = $2;
  for (i in vname) {
     if (i > indent) {delete vname[i]}}
  if (length($3) > 0) {
     vn=""; for (i=0; i<indent; i++) {vn=(vn)(vname[i])("_")}
     printf("%s%s%s=\"%s\"\n", "'$prefix'",vn, $2, $3);
  }
}'
}
# read yaml file
eval $(parse_yaml config_file.yml "")
# access yaml content
echo $sample_sql
```

I am not able to understand how I can iterate through this.

Comment: Just write your own simple bash parser. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014632/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-from-a-linux-shell-script?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any reason why you can't use python?

It should come pre-installed with most linux distributions, and it means you don't have to re-invent the wheel!

To setup:

```
pip install pyyaml
```

Then your script is:

```
import yaml
f = open('config_file.yml')
yaml_file = yaml.safe_load(f)
for sample in yaml_file:
    print yaml_file[sample]["sql"]
```

To run:

```
python <script_name>.py
```

Comment: As specified in the PyYAML documentation `yaml.load()` can be unsafe. There is no excuse for using that, instead of `yaml.safe_load()`. You should also not polute your system's Python installation with `pip` installs, always create a virtualenv for your utiltities, so `pip` installs cannot break your system.

Comment: Yes i finally switched to python... this works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep` or `pcregrep` with something like this:

```
$ while read -r line; do
  echo $line
done < <(grep -oP "sql: \"\K.+?(?=\")" config_file.yml)
```

Output:

```
select * from dbname.tableName where sampleDate>='2018-07-20';
select * from dbname.tableName where sampleDate<='2016-05-25';
```

In macOS, you could use `pcregrep -o "sql: \"\K.+?(?=\")" config_file.yml`

The `\K` can be read as excluding everything to the left before it and return only the right part `.+?(?=\")` until `"` is found.

Now if your `yaml` is more complex you could give a try too [yq](https://yq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`pip install yq`) and then, for example, to get the `sql` values you could do:

```
$ yq -r '.sample.sql' config_file.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the script a bit to include the keys in a space separated list.

note: this method requires a prefix.

```
function parse_yaml {
  local prefix=$2
  local s='[[:space:]]*' w='[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' fs=$(echo @|tr @ '\034')
  sed -ne "s|^\($s\):|\1|" \
    -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s[\"']\(.*\)[\"']$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" \
    -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\(.*\)$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p"  $1 |
  awk -F$fs '{
    indent = length($1)/2;
    vname[indent] = $2;
    for (i in vname) {if (i > indent) {delete vname[i]}}
    if (length($3) > 0) {
      vn=""; for (i=0; i<indent; i++) {vn=(vn)(vname[i])("_")}
      printf("%s%s%s=\"%s\"\n", "'$prefix'",vn, $2, $3);
      printf("%1$s%2$s=\"${%1$s%2$s} %3$s\"\n", "'$prefix'",vn, $2, $3);
      printf("%1$s=\"${%1$s} %2$s\"\n", "'$prefix'",vn, $2, $3);
    }
  }'
}
```

usage

```
eval $(parse_yaml "config_file.yml" "CONF_")

# to specify all keys (apart from the final level)
for key in $CONF_; do
  echo "$key"
done

# or to list keys of a specific object
for key in $CONF_sample_; do
  echo "$key"
done
```

Note: This method is limited to the core level, and final level. Someone else may be able to modify this to use in between levels if they need that feature.