# How to convert a json response into yaml in bash

Tags: json, bash, yaml, jq

I read data from a json file with jq. I wanna append the results into a yaml file, but I dont get it working. I am quite new to shell programming. My goal is to append that "users" to an existing "users"-Array in a yaml file.

This is my json file:

```
#$DEFAULTS_FILE

{"users":
  [
    {"name":"pi",
      "gecos": "Hypriot Pirate",
      "sudo":"ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL",
      "shell": "/bin/bash",
      "groups":"users,docker,video",
      "plain_text_passwd":"pi",
      "lock_passwd":"false",
      "ssh_pwauth":"true",
      "chpasswd": {"expire": false}
    },
    {"name":"admin",
      "gecos": "Hypriot Pirate",
      "sudo":"ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL",
      "shell": "/bin/bash",
      "primary-group": "users",
      "groups":"users,docker,adm,dialout,audio,plugdev,netdev,video",
      "ssh-import-id":"None",
      "plain_text_passwd":"pi",
      "lock_passwd":"true",
      "ssh_pwauth":"true",
      "chpasswd": "{expire: false}",
      "ssh-authorized-keys": ["ssh-rsa abcdefg1234567890 YOUR_KEY@YOURHOST.local"]
    }
  ]
  }
```

I filter it with that:

`cat $DEFAULTS_FILE | jq .users`

I have no clue how to convert that json into a yaml.

My expected result should be:

```
users:
  - name:                pi
    gecos:               "Hypriot Pirate"
    sudo:                ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    shell:               /bin/bash
    groups:              users,docker,video
    plain_text_passwd:   pi
    lock_passwd:         false
    ssh_pwauth:          true
    chpasswd: { expire:  false }
  - name:                admin
    primary-group:       users
    shell:               /bin/bash
    sudo:                ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups:              users,docker,adm,dialout,audio,plugdev,netdev,video
    ssh-import-id:       None
```

I tried to use a second tool called `yq` which is similar to `jq` and can write yaml files. But I have no positive progress.

*EDIT*

I know that I can add content to the yaml with that:

`yq w -i "my.yml" "users[+]" "some content"`

But I dont know how to merge my json into that.

Any help or hint would be nice, thank you in advance...

Comment: You can use `python`/`perl` which have in-built `YAML` and `JSON` modules - https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12218/convert-yaml-to-json

Comment: That's exact the opposite direction

Comment: Bash itself is not a good platform for this. Find an existing tool, or write one in e.g. Python. Depending on your preferred language, it should not be hard to find an existing question on Stack Overflow with suggestions; [here's a search for Python](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+convert+json+to+yaml+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.  In particular, a sample my.yml (i.e. input) would be helpful.

Comment: `yq r input.json`  should do the job.

Comment: Thank you all, I followed @Inian `s approach to write a 'lil script in Ruby. and @Jeff Mercado. I don't know why this is quoted, but this is exactly what the program spit.

Comment: as @AHT pointed out `yq r` works (as JSON is a subset of YAML); the output should be pretty-printed, though to make it "look more like YAML": `yq -P r input.json`; see also https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/convert#json-to-yaml

Comment: [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.1/#id2759572) says: "every JSON file is also a valid YAML file"

Answer (score 92):

`yq` a yaml wrapper for `jq`

###### With yq 4.18.1+

```sh
cat "$DEFAULTS_FILE" | yq -P    # or yq --prettyPrint
```

See: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1

**With yq version 4.8.0:**

`cat $DEFAULTS_FILE | yq e -P -`

- `e` or `eval` handles file separately. `ea` or `eval-all` will merge files first.
- `-P` or `--prettyPrint` YAML output
- `-` from STDIN

*Note: you can go the other way (yaml to json) too `yq e -j file.yaml`*

**With yq version 3.3.2:**

`cat $DEFAULTS_FILE | yq r -P -`

- `r` read
- `-P` --prettyPrint
- `-` from STDIN

Comment: You're a mad lad!  Thanks mate!

Comment: This answer needs an edit. Your `yq` example is an implementation of mikefarah/yq, which is NOT a wrapper over `jq`. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64625920/5291015)

Comment: If using mikefarah/yq V4, you need to use the following command: `yq eval '.. style= ""' sample.json` or `cat sample.json | yq eval '.. style= ""' -`. See https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/convert

Comment: Actually, all you need is `cat $DEFAULTS_FILE | yq -y`

Comment: With [`mikefarah/yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) version 4, `yq eval -P` is the correct syntax.

Comment: With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) version 4.15, `yq e -P` and `yq eval -P` both works fine.

Comment: Tangentially, you want to avoid the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 40):

```sh
function yaml_validate {
  python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin.read())'
}

function yaml2json {
  python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; print(json.dumps(yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin.read())))'
}

function yaml2json_pretty {
  python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; print(json.dumps(yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin.read()), indent=2, sort_keys=False))'
}

function json_validate {
  python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; json.loads(sys.stdin.read())'
}

function json2yaml {
  python -c 'import sys, yaml, json; print(yaml.dump(json.loads(sys.stdin.read())))'
}
```

More Bash tricks at http://github.com/frgomes/bash-scripts

Comment: Possibly superfluous in light of `yq` and `jq`, but very nicely done, and probably has some good applications.

Comment: Ha! As it happens, I ran into errors installing `yq` just now in a gpc ai notebook. so, I guess these will come in very handy!

Comment: perhaps the best answer,as it does not make you install `yq`

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure what rules you're using to get to your expected result. It seems like you're randomly applying different rules to how the values are being converted.

As I understand it, scalar values are just output as is (with potential encoding), objects are output as key/value pairs, and array objects are output with a `-` for every item. The indentation associates what's part of what.

So based on those rules if you're going to use jq:

```
def yamlify:
    (objects | to_entries[] | (.value | type) as $type |
        if $type == "array" then
            "\(.key):", (.value | yamlify)
        elif $type == "object" then
            "\(.key):", "    \(.value | yamlify)"
        else
            "\(.key):\t\(.value)"
        end
    )
    // (arrays | select(length > 0)[] | [yamlify] |
        "  - \(.[0])", "    \(.[1:][])"
    )
    // .
    ;
```

Then to use it, add it to your `.jq` file and use it:

```
$ jq -r yamlify input.json
users:
  - name:       pi
    gecos:      Hypriot Pirate
    sudo:       ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    shell:      /bin/bash
    groups:     users,docker,video
    plain_text_passwd:  pi
    lock_passwd:        false
    ssh_pwauth: true
    chpasswd:
        expire: false
  - name:       admin
    gecos:      Hypriot Pirate
    sudo:       ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    shell:      /bin/bash
    primary-group:      users
    groups:     users,docker,adm,dialout,audio,plugdev,netdev,video
    ssh-import-id:      None
    plain_text_passwd:  pi
    lock_passwd:        true
    ssh_pwauth: true
    chpasswd:   {expire: false}
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa abcdefg1234567890 YOUR_KEY@YOURHOST.local
```

---

Here's another variation that aligns the values

```
def yamlify2:
    (objects | to_entries | (map(.key | length) | max + 2) as $w |
        .[] | (.value | type) as $type |
        if $type == "array" then
            "\(.key):", (.value | yamlify2)
        elif $type == "object" then
            "\(.key):", "    \(.value | yamlify2)"
        else
            "\(.key):\(" " * (.key | $w - length))\(.value)"
        end
    )
    // (arrays | select(length > 0)[] | [yamlify2] |
        "  - \(.[0])", "    \(.[1:][])"
    )
    // .
    ;
```

```
$ jq -r yamlify2 input.json
users:
  - name:               pi
    gecos:              Hypriot Pirate
    sudo:               ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    shell:              /bin/bash
    groups:             users,docker,video
    plain_text_passwd:  pi
    lock_passwd:        false
    ssh_pwauth:         true
    chpasswd:
        expire:  false
  - name:                 admin
    gecos:                Hypriot Pirate
    sudo:                 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    shell:                /bin/bash
    primary-group:        users
    groups:               users,docker,adm,dialout,audio,plugdev,netdev,video
    ssh-import-id:        None
    plain_text_passwd:    pi
    lock_passwd:          true
    ssh_pwauth:           true
    chpasswd:             {expire: false}
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa abcdefg1234567890 YOUR_KEY@YOURHOST.local
```

Comment: really cool. love it, unfortunately, it breaks for multiline string values..

Comment: Based on the code of @Jeff Mercado I added some code to support multiline strings and escaping of single quotes. See my answer "Solution in jq (without other tools)".

Answer (score 14):

#### `yq eval -P`

with [`mikefarah/yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) version 4.0 (released December 2020), installable via most Unix-like OS package managers: via Homebrew for macOS (`brew install yq`), Debian with `apt` (`apt install yq`), Alpine with `apk` (`apk add yq`), etc.

See [Working with JSON](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/convert).

> To read in json, just pass in a json file instead of yaml, it will just work - as json is a subset of yaml. However, you will probably want to use the Style Operator or `--prettyPrint/-P` flag to make look more like an idiomatic yaml document.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest using [`yq`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) with `-y` option

```
$ pip3 install yq # requires jq

$ cat in.json | yq -y
users:
  - name: pi
    gecos: Hypriot Pirate
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    shell: /bin/bash
    groups: users,docker,video
    plain_text_passwd: pi
    lock_passwd: 'false'
    ssh_pwauth: 'true'
    chpasswd:
      expire: false
  - name: admin
    gecos: Hypriot Pirate
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    shell: /bin/bash
    primary-group: users
    groups: users,docker,adm,dialout,audio,plugdev,netdev,video
    ssh-import-id: None
    plain_text_passwd: pi
    lock_passwd: 'true'
    ssh_pwauth: 'true'
    chpasswd: '{expire: false}'
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa abcdefg1234567890 YOUR_KEY@YOURHOST.local
```

Answer (score 9):

I've used ruby to write my json content into yaml.

As for your example, it can be achieved like this:

```
cat $DEFAULTS_FILE | jq .users | ruby -ryaml -rjson -e 'puts YAML.dump(JSON.parse(STDIN.read))' > my.yml
```

Comment: While I can't stand ruby, my machine already had it installed.  I was able to create an alias and pipe it to this alias.  Thank you, this has been very helpful!

Comment: Exact same sentiment here.

Answer (score 5):

Another oneliner:

```sh
python -c 'import yaml, sys; print(yaml.dump(yaml.load(open(sys.argv[1])), default_flow_style=False))' input.json
```

(exploiting the fact that valid json is also valid yaml)

And yaml to json:

```sh
python -c 'import yaml, json, sys; print(json.dumps(yaml.load(open(sys.argv[1])), indent=2))' input.yaml
```

Comment: Your yaml-to-json oneliner fails with `found character '\t' that cannot start any token`; it's the same error message `yq` reports, which must work similarly. Richard Gomes' one-liner works fine.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution in jq (without other tools)

Based on the code of @Jeff Mercado in this post I added support for multiline strings and escaping for single quotes.

```
# purpose: converts Json to Yaml
# remarks:
#   You can use 'yq -y' to convert json to yaml, but ...
#     * this function can be used several times within a single jq program
#     * this function may be faster than using yq
#     * maybe yq is not available in your environment
#
# input: any Json
# output: json converted to yaml
def toYaml:
   def handleMultilineString($level):
      reduce ([match("\n+"; "g")]                       # find groups of '\n'
              | sort_by(-.offset))[] as $match
             (.; .[0:$match.offset + $match.length] +
                 "\n\("    " * $level)" +               # add one extra '\n' for every group of '\n's. Add indention for each new line
                 .[$match.offset + $match.length:]);

   def toYamlString($level):
      if type == "string"
      then handleMultilineString($level)
           | sub("'"; "''"; "g")           # escape single quotes
           | "'\(.)'"                      # wrap in single quotes
      else .
      end;

   def _toYaml($level):
      (objects | to_entries[] |
          if (.value | type) == "array" then
              "\(.key):", (.value | _toYaml($level))
          elif (.value | type) == "object" then
              "\(.key):", "\("    ")\(.value | _toYaml($level))"
          else
              "\(.key): \(.value | toYamlString($level))"
          end
      )
      // (arrays | select(length > 0)[] | [_toYaml($level)] |
          "  - \(.[0])", "\("    ")\(.[1:][])"
      )
      // .;

   _toYaml(1);
```

### Example usage

`File 'containsMultilineStrings.json'`

```
{
  "response": {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "greeting\nthat's all folks\n\n\n"
  }
}
```

`jq -r 'toYaml' < containsMultilineStrings.json`

```
response:
    code: 200
    message: 'greeting

    that''s all folks



    '
```

`jq -r 'toYaml' containsMultilineStrings.json | yq` (roundtrip)

```
{
  "response": {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "greeting\nthat's all folks\n\n\n"
  }
}
```

### Test

You can test the correctness of the function `toYaml` by converting json to yaml and than back to json using yq.

`FILE='containsMultilineStrings.json'; diff <(cat "$FILE") <(jq -r 'toYaml' $FILE | yq)`

### Performance

A quick benchmark shows a reduced runtime of the function `toYaml` compared to the use of yq.
On my computer, I measured:

`time for i in {1..100}; do yq -y > /dev/null < containsMultilineStrings.json; done`

> 8.4 sec

`time for i in {1..100}; do jq -r 'toYaml' > /dev/null containsMultilineStrings.json; done`

> 3.4 sec

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq). It is a port of jq with support for reading and writing yaml. It can be installed via GitHub releases, homebrew, and zero install. The command for your question would be:

```
cat test.json | gojq --yaml-output > test.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the awesome library `yq`

```bash
# install yq on macOS
brew install yq
```

Then run the following command

```bash
cat file.json | yq -P > file.yml
```

You can also convert and save a JSON Response into a YAML file, for example:

```bash
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/typicode/demo/master/db.json | yq -P > example.yml
```