# How to insert or add a field in a yaml after a specific key in yq

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, jq, yq

I have a k8s yaml file with below block

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
```

and I want to add below block after "spec:"

```
selector:
  matchLabels:
    app: test-app
```

The file is huge and has many "spec:" fields, so it should be added at the first match.

Final file content should look like this :

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
```

I came up with this working solution using yq with correct indentation but it appends at the end of the file, Its painful to maintain and reading similar 100's of files.

```
yq  -i -y '.spec += {selector:{matchLabels:{app:"test-app"}}}' filename.yaml
```

Any answers with tools like sed or awk are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `yq`, but I know it supports limited [JSON I/O](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/convert). Here's a solution to the structural problem with `jq`:

```
.spec |= ({selector: {matchLabels: {app: "test-app"}}} + .)
```

Maybe worth a shot in native `yq`?

Sample pipeline (untested):

```
yq r -j k8s.yaml | jq "$script" | yq r --prettyPrint
```

There are also [these jq yamlifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53330236/11053344) by the incorrigible Jeff Mercado.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```
$ yq --yaml-output '.spec |= ({selector: {matchLabels: {app: "test-app"}}} + .)' </tmp/your-yaml-file.yaml 

spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
```

Since you mentioned you have hundreds of files and each has many `spec` elements, it's unclear if this will solve your actual problem but hopefully it can be of help. Good luck!

Comment: OP specifically mentioned the order of the key-value pairs as a requirement. This is a long-winded equivalent of the example script.

Comment: Agreed; his answer was the same using syntax I was unfamiliar with. Updated.

Comment: this leads to "Error: unknown flag: --yaml-output"

Comment: @DanielMethner There are 2 yq's -- the 'Andrey Kislyuk' yq and the 'Mike Farah' yq. The Kisyluk has the `--yaml-output` flag; it appears the Farah yq does not (never used it but I just grepped the source and didn't see that flag). Perhaps you are using the Farah yq?

Answer (score -3):

You want a pickup-truck solution.  I'm suggesting an Earth-mover instead.
 (ATTENTION: Following requires Node.JS, Java-8 and command-line Git installed)..

```
npm install -g commander@2.20.0
npm install -g @asux.org/cli-npm
export NODE_PATH=`npm root -g`
asux
```

The above does installation.

---

For what you want.. 
Create a `/tmp/batch-file.txt` containing the following lines.

```
## This is a comment.  No temporary files are created by this.
saveTo !ORIGINALINPUT
yaml read spec
saveTo !SAVED
useAsInput !ORIGINALINPUT
yaml delete 'spec/*'
yaml insert spec @/tmp/HugeSelectorFile.yaml
yaml insert spec !SAVED
```

Run the command:

```
asux yaml batch @/tmp/batch-file.txt -i ./YOURORIGINAL.yaml -o ./NEW.yaml
```

ASSUMPTIONS:
1) Your original YAML file is `./YOURORIGINAL.yaml`
2) You want a new file called `./NEW.yaml`
3) Your "huge selector" file is called `/tmp/HugeSelectorFile.yaml` (see 2nd-last lime in batch.txt above)

NOTE: The '@' character prefixing file-names is by-design (as without that '@' character, it means you are passing in JSON/YAML **in-line** within the command-line).

More can be found at https://github.com/org-asux/org-ASUX.github.io/wiki/Welcome-to-WIKI-for-org.ASUX