# Bash : Split Array into KV pairs

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on a script, where via JQ I am getting Environment variables and I need them in KV pairs for other type of file. Currently, i have the elements as follows in a Bash array

```
DD_TRACE_CLI_ENABLED:true
PRODUCT:buy_box
TRACE_ID:$NOMAD_ALLOC_ID
```

Now, When I am printing, I need it like this:

```
- name: DD_TRACE_CLI_ENABLED
  value: true
- name: PRODUCT
  value: buy_box
```

My current code

```
if [ ! -z "$env_params" -a "$env_params" != " " ]; then
env_params_as_array=(${env_params//,/ })
for each in "${env_params_as_array[@]}"
do
echo $each
echo -e "${myCustomIndentTab}- $each" >> values-$1.yaml
done
fi
```

How can I achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: It seems like you want to generate YAML. With the data coming from `jq` why don't you use `yq`?

Comment: If you are using `jq` anyway, probably use that tool to format the output the way you want it. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68168384/874188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash array:

```bash
env_params_as_array=(
    DD_TRACE_CLI_ENABLED:true
    PRODUCT:buy_box
    TRACE_ID:"$NOMAD_ALLOC_ID"
)
```

printing it the way you want:

```bash
for p in "${env_params_as_array[@]}"
do
    IFS=':' read -r k v <<< "$p"
    printf -- '%s- name: %s\n  value: %s\n' "$myCustomIndentTab" "$k" "$v"
done > "values-$1.yaml"
```