# How to get string from file in bash?

Tags: bash

I have file that is **not** JSON 
and I want to get string of 'name' from the file but only name with key type with value 'typeX'
Input :

```
ID : id
mySer:
   - name : xyz
     type : typeX

myServ2:
   - name : wyz
    params:
     - name :ppp
```

Output

```
name : xyz
or xyz
```

I tried

```
awk '/"name":/{flag=1;next}/^$/{flag=0}flag'
```

but I got all the names

Comment: It is not a json

Comment: Please add example data to your question, plus the desired output

Comment: @hek2mgl - I updated the question

Comment: Looks like yaml

Comment: yes it is yaml and I need it with bash script

Comment: Sorry, why do you ask 'I need to parse something which is not JSON' instead of 'How to parse yaml'? That doesn't make sense for me. I'm sure you'll find answers if you search for `How to parse yaml from bash`

Comment: Take a look at `man grep`. `grep -B 1 'type : typeX$' file | grep -Po '\Kname : xyz$'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a YAML file from a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014632/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-from-a-linux-shell-script)

Comment: Most *good* answers for the question "how to parse yams from bash" are going to suggest not using `bash`; I'm not aware of any good standalone programs for parsing Yaml (like `jq` does for JSON). `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, etc do not qualify as "good standalone programs for parsing Yaml".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `yq` is available, please try:

```
yq -r '.[][]? | select (.type == "typeX") | .name' file.yml
```

output:

```
xyz
```

`file.xml` looks like:

```
ID : id
mySer:
   - name : xyz
     type : typeX

myServ2:
   - name : wyz
     params:
     - name :ppp
```

(The posted file looks like improperly indented in the line of `params`.)

In most platform you can install `yq` with:

```
$ pip install yp
```

Before using `yq`, you also have to install its dependency, `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

test.yml:

```
ID : id
mySer:
   - name : xyz
     type : typeX

myServ2:
   - name : wyz
    params:
     - name :ppp
myExample:
   - name : levi
     type : typeX
```

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

str=`cat test.yml`;


function match {
    MATCHES=() 
    local mstr=$1 re="($2)(.*)"
    while [[ -n $mstr && $mstr =~ $re ]]; do
        MATCHES+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
        mstr=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    done
}

match "$str" 'name : [a-zA-Z0-9]+\s+type : typeX' 

for (( v=0; v < ${#MATCHES[@]}; v++)); do
    echo ":: ${MATCHES[$v]}";
done
```

The output:

```
:: name : xyz
     type : typeX
:: name : levi
     type : typeX
```

However, if you only want to see the name lines, you can pipe that into grep ( | grep name ) where you only show name and then the output would look like this:

```
:: name : xyz
:: name : levi
```