# Parse a nested variable from YAML file in bash

Tags: bash, kubernetes, yaml

A complex `.yaml` file from [this link](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.3/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubernetes-datastore/calico-networking/1.7/calico.yaml) needs to be fed into a bash script that runs as part of an automation program running on an EC2 instance of Amazon Linux 2.  Note that the `.yaml` file in the link above contains many objects, and that I need to extract one of the environment variables defined inside one of the many objects that are defined in the file.

> Specifically, how can I extract the `192.168.0.0/16` value of the `CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR` variable into a bash variable?

```
        - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR
          value: "192.168.0.0/16"
```

I have read a lot of other postings and blog entries about parsing flatter, simpler `.yaml` files, but none of those other examples show how to extract a nested value like the `value` of `CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR` in this question.

Comment: `CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR` **is** a value (for the key `name`), it doesn't have a value.

Answer (score 3):

```
MYVAR=$(\
curl https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.3/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubernetes-datastore/calico-networking/1.7/calico.yaml | \
grep -A 1 CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR | \
grep value | \
cut -d ':' -f2 | \
tr -d ' "')
```

Replace `curl https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.3/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubernetes-datastore/calico-networking/1.7/calico.yaml` with however you're sourcing the file. That gets piped to `grep -A 1 CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR`. This gives you 2 lines of text: the name line, and the value line. That gets piped to `grep value`, which now gives us the line we want with just the value. That gets piped to `cut -d ':' -f2` which uses the colon as a delimiter and gives us the second field. `$(...)` executes the enclosed script, and it is assigned to `MYVAR`. After this script, `echo $MYVAR` should produce `192.168.0.0/16`.

Comment: You could just do `grep -A1 CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR | awk 'END{print $2}'`

Answer (score 3):

As others are commenting, it is recommended to make use of `yq` (along with `jq`) if available.
Then please try the following:

```
value=$(yq -r 'recurse | select(.name? == "CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR") | .value' "calico.yaml")
echo "$value"
```

Output:

```
192.168.0.0/16
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to install new dependencies, and are planning on dealing with lots of yaml files, [`yq`](https://yq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a wrapper around jq that can handle yaml. It'd allow a safe (non-grep) way of accessing nested yaml values.

Usage would look something like `MY_VALUE=$(yq '.myValue.nested.value' < config-file.yaml)`

Alternatively, [How can I parse a YAML file from a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014632/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-from-a-linux-shell-script) has a bash-only parser that you could use to get your value.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this is to use a scripting language and a YAML parsing library to extract the field you're interested in.

Here's an example of how to do it in Python. If you were doing this for real you'd probably split it out into multiple functions and have better error reporting. This is literally just to illustrate some of the difficulties caused by the format of `calico.yaml`, which is several YAML documents concatenated together, not just one. You also have to loop over some of the lists internal to the document in order to extract the field you're interested in.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import yaml

def foo():
    with open('/tmp/calico.yaml', 'r') as fil:
        docs = yaml.safe_load_all(fil)
        doc = None
        for candidate in docs:
            if candidate["kind"] == "DaemonSet":
                doc = candidate
                break
        else:
            raise ValueError("no YAML document of kind DaemonSet")
        l1 = doc["spec"]
        l2 = l1["template"]
        l3 = l2["spec"]
        l4 = l3["containers"]
        for containers_item in l4:
            l5 = containers_item["env"]
            env = l5
            for entry in env:
                if entry["name"] == "CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR":
                    return entry["value"]
    raise ValueError("no CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR entry")

print(foo())
```

---

However, sometimes you need a solution *right now* and shell scripts are very good at that.

If you're hitting an API endpoint, then the YAML will usually be pretty-printed so you can get away with extracting text in ways that won't work on arbitrary YAML.

Something like the following should be fairly robust:

```
cat </tmp/calico.yaml | grep -A1 CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR | grep value: | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' "'
```

Although it's worth checking at the end with a regex that the extracted value really is valid IPv4 CIDR notation.

The key thing here is `grep -A1 CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR` .

The two-element dictionary you mentioned (shown below) will always appear as one chunk since it's a subtree of the YAML document.

```
    - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR
      value: "192.168.0.0/16"
```

The keys in `calico.yaml` are not sorted alphabetically in general, but in `{"name": <something>, "value": <something else>}` constructions, `name` does consistently appear before `value`.

Comment: Two problems here: you are using PyYAML's `load_all()` which is documented to be unsafe, and there is no excuse not to use `safe_load_all()`; the OP doesn't say that that is YAML 1.1 (replaced ten years ago by YAML 1.2, which PyYAML cannot handle)

Comment: @Anthon, Thank you. I tried looking through the project calico repo to see if I could find any mention of the version of YAML being used and it isn't explicitly documented. However, definite YAML-<=1.1-isms like `off` only seem to appear in certain vagrant-related files.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems there:

- How to read a YAML document from a file with multiple documents
- How to select the key you want from that YAML document

I have guessed that you need the YAML document of kind 'DaemonSet' from reading Gregory Nisbett's answer.

I will try to only use tools that are likely to be already installed on your system because you mentioned you want to do this in a Bash script. I assume you have JQ because it is hard to do much in Bash without it!

For the YAML library I tend to use Ruby for this because:

- Most systems have a Ruby
- Ruby's Psych library has been bundled since Ruby 1.9
- The PyYAML library in Python is a bit inflexible and sometimes broken compared to Ruby's in my experience
- The YAML library in Perl is often not installed by default

It was suggested to use [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), but that won't help so much in this case because you still need a tool that can extract the YAML document.

Having extracted the document I am going to again use Ruby to save the file as JSON. Then we can use jq.

**Extracting the YAML document**

To get the YAML document using Ruby and save it as JSON:

```rb
url=...
curl -s $url | \
  ruby -ryaml -rjson -e \
    "puts YAML.load_stream(ARGF.read)
      .select{|doc| doc['kind']=='DaemonSet'}[0].to_json" \
  | jq . > calico.json
```

Further explanation:

- The YAML.load_stream reads the YAML documents and returns them all as an Array
- ARGF.read reads from a file passed via STDIN
- Ruby's select allows easy selection of the YAML document according to its kind key
- Then we take the element 4 and convert to JSON.

I pass that response through `jq .` so that it's formatted for human readability but that step isn't really necessary. I could do the same in Ruby but I'm guessing you want Ruby code kept to a minimum.

**Selecting the key you want**

To select the key you want the following JQ query can be used:

```sh
jq -r \
  '.spec.template.spec.containers[].env[] | select(.name=="CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR") | .value' \
  calico.json
```

Further explanation:

- The first part `spec.template.spec.containers[].env[]` iterates for all containers and for all envs inside them
- Then we select the Hash where the name key equals CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR and return the value
- The -r removes the quotes around the string

Putting it all together:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

url='https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.3/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubernetes-datastore/calico-networking/1.7/calico.yaml'

curl -s $url | \
  ruby -ryaml -rjson -e \
    "puts YAML.load_stream(ARGF.read)
      .select{|doc| doc['kind']=='DaemonSet'}[0].to_json" \
  | jq . > calico.json

jq -r \
  '.spec.template.spec.containers[].env[] | select(.name=="CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR") | .value' \
  calico.json
```

Testing:

```
▶ bash test.sh
192.168.0.0/16
```