# bash Iterate over a hash table

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a read the output of a function into a variable.

The data looks like this

```
---
data:
  pkg:
    -
      NAME: 'bob'
      FEATURE: Big
    -
      NAME: 'sue'
      FEATURE: Tall
    -
      NAME: 'jim'
      FEATURE: Slim
```

I see examples of iterating over an array.
Those examples always create the array by hand.

Is there a way to transform the hash into an array?  How do I do that? Or can I deal with it in this form?

I'd like to echo the FEATURE of each pkg.

Comment: You haven't seen examples like `arrayName[$key]=$value` to create array elements dynamically?

Comment: Why do you think you need a multidimensional array? Bash doesn't have them.

Comment: Well, if you really need the data structure in bash, you must "simulate" multidimensional array. If I need to `echo` all values of some dictionary key from a YML, I would do this with `grep` and `sed`.

Comment: You should switch to a language with a real YAML parser; `grep` and `sed` are not sufficient.

Comment: This would probably be trivial to do using [yq](https://yq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

The yaml in your example represents an array of dictionaries. Bash doesn't do multidimensional arrays of any sort.

You can, however, simulate the result by parsing your data into *parallel* arrays, so that `${name[0]}` of `bob` corresponds by its zero index with `${feature[0]}` of `Big`.

The real problem is manually parsing YAML, which I don't recommend.

If you really need to dive into that, check out [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014632/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-from-a-linux-shell-script) which has some options.