# Cross using yml variables in the bash script

Tags: bash, gitlab

Below I have shown my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
variables:
  timezone: "Europe/Vienna"

stages:
  - style
  - build

style:
  stage: style
  script:
  - sudo docker run --rm -v $PWD:/code omercnet/pycodestyle

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    blla blla
    - sudo docker exec ${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG} /bin/bash -c "./install.sh"
    blla blla
```

Next, it is my install.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
blla blla 

echo -e "\nmx_download_url: https://dl.bintray.com/random" >> /etc/random-installer/setup.yml
sed -i s+old text+new text+g etc/random-installer/setup.yml

blla blla
```

How I can use the value of the variable **timezone** from the yml file in the **new text** in the bash script?

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work. 
Maybe my bash it's different from perl and doesn't recognize those functions...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014632/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-from-a-linux-shell-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timezone` is visible as environment variable for the gitlab jobs, however `install.sh` scripts is running from another context - it's executed by docker. Docker itself has access to `$timezone`, however containers it's operating with don't.

To solve your problem you can explicitly pass it:

```
- sudo docker exec -e TIMEZONE=$timezone ${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG} /bin/bash -c "./install.sh"
```

This will set environment variable `$TIMEZONE` for install.sh *inside* the container.

Comment: So I need to set TIMEZONE as an env variable in my runner then associate it in this command with the timezone variable within the yml file?
Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: `envrionment:` section in `.gitlab-ci.yml` is already defining environment variables for your jobs, that's why I used `$timezone` (lowercase) in my example.

I put value from environment section (`$timezone`) into environment variable inside docker container (`$TIMEZONE`).

After replacing `sudo docker exec ...` by the example I provided you will be already able to use `$TIMEZONE` inside `install.sh`, no extra changes are required.