# use self reference in `yq` write command

Tags: yq

I have a yaml file that looks something like this:

```yaml
a:
  desc:
  value: 1
b:
  desc:
  value: 2
# ...
```

I want to convert it to this:

```yaml
a: 1
b: 2
# ...
```

In `yq` v2, I used the command `.[] |= .value'` to update each element of the array to the value in the `.value` field. Is there a way to do this with `yq` v3?

```yaml
cat config.yaml |  yq w - "*" "*.value"
```

yields

```
a: *.value
b: *.value
# ...
``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your claim seems to be contradicting each other. There are two versions of `yq` implementations out there. A [python implementation](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) as a wrapper over `jq` and [other written in Go.](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64742436) that covers in details about those versions.

When you said you used `.[] |= .value` in `yq` v2, that's actually not the Go version, but the version with the Python wrapper over `jq`, since that syntax matches its DSL. But the other attempt  `yq w - "*" "*.value"` seems to be the actual Go version.

Since there is an uncertainty around which version of `yq` in installed for you, I'll try to provide my view in both the versions

**kislyuk's yq**

```sh
yq -y '.[] |= .value' yaml
```

**mikefarah's yq**

The Go version does not have dynamic transformational capabilities like its Python version and does not support this type of update directly. Because [the write/new](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/commands/write-update) field creations syntax is simply

```
yq w <yaml_file> <path_expression> <new value>
```

where the new value is *not* an expression but a *literal* value. Had it supported expressions, we could have conjured up a way to do the transformation. The Go version is otherwise good, but lacking support in some key transformational capabilities.

P.S. I've raised a GitHub feature request to allow such transformations. See https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/602

---

As of today Dec 21st, 2020, `yq` v4 is in beta and supports this transformation. Download the [v4 version](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/4.0.0) and try

```
yq eval '.[] |= .value' test.yml
```