# Programatically apply a single resource from a multi resource Kubernetes YAML file

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubectl, yq

I have a file with three configmaps in it, like the one below.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  TEST: "one"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config-one
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  TEST: "two"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config-two
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  TEST: "three"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-config-three
```

I'm trying to apply only `test-config-three` to the cluster. I know I can break that out into its own file and run `kubectl apply -f test-config-three.yaml`, but is there a way to do that without having to create a new file?

I was hoping to be able to do something like:

```sh
cat file.yml | yq <get only test-config-three> | kubectl apply -f -
```

But `yq` doesn't seem to support finding a single resource in a file. I also looked at tools like [kubesplit](https://github.com/looztra/kubesplit) but they tend to output all resources to separate files.

Is there a way to isolate and output a single resource from a yaml file containing multiple resources without creating a new file?

**Update**

Thanks to @Inian's answer below, I was able to get this full command working.

```sh
cat file.yml | yq e 'select(.data.TEST == "three")' - | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: Which version of `yq` are you using? The Python or the Go version? Post the output of `yq --version`

Comment: I can't believe that someone out there had a use-case exactly as that of mine. This helped me out! Thank you so much OP and @Inian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two versions of `yq` implemented, one in Python and one in Go as I've highlighted in my answer at [How can I parse a YAML file from a Linux shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64742436/5291015)

Using the Python version - kislyuk/yq

```sh
yq -y 'select(.data.TEST == "three")' yaml
```

Go version - mikefarah/yq

```sh
yq e 'select(.data.TEST == "three")' yaml
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm using the Go version.

Answer (score 1):

If you have python you can try following

```
export MYFILE=file.yml
export DOC_NUMBER=2

python3 -c "import yaml; print(yaml.dump(list(yaml.safe_load_all(open('"$MYFILE"')))["$DOC_NUMBER"]))" | kubectl apply -f -
```

`yaml.safe_load_all(open('"$MYFILE"'))` loads all the documents in the yaml file into a list. Then you are selecting "$DOC_NUMBER" document with `["$DOC_NUMBER"]`.

`yaml.dump` would dump the loaded object back into yaml format which is then printed.