# How to read a yaml or env file using bash

Tags: bash, yaml

I have a `.yml` file and it has content like below:

```
env_values:
 stage: build
 before_script: some-value
```

So I need to read and get the values for `stage` and `before_script`, so they will have `build` and `some-value` respectively.

Is there a good easy workaround in bash scripting to read this file and get the values?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014632/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-from-a-linux-shell-script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume your .yml file is `t.yml`, this Bash script gets the 2 values you need:

```sh
arr=($(cat t.yml | grep "stage:"))
stage=${arr[1]}
echo $stage

arr=($(cat t.yml | grep "before_script:"))
before_script=${arr[1]}
echo $before_script
```