# Fetch variables values from yml and pass to shell script?

Tags: bash, yaml

data.yml

```
variables:
  count: "100"
  name: "sss"
  pass: "123"
```

file.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Details are "$name":"$pass" - Total value "$count"
```

I need to fetch the variable values from data.yml and pass to file.sh

calling file.sh should give Output:

```
Details are sss:123 - Total value 100
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as _bash_  **and** _powershell_?

Comment: @phd i have updated the tags remove the downvote. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read name value pairs from `yq` and use bash `printf -v` to initialize variables.
A little over the top, but a nice way to initialize a script.
Note that adding variables does not change the while loop.

file.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while read -r key val; do
    printf -v "$key" "$val"
done < <(yq '.variables[] | key + " " + .' data.yml)

echo "Details are $name: $pass - Total value $count"
echo 'Some extra variables:'
echo "\$address: $address, \$phone: $phone, \$url: $url"
```

data.yml

```yaml
variables:
  count: "100"
  name: "sss"
  pass: "123"
  address: "42 Terrapin Station"
  phone: "999-999-9999"
  url: "http://www.example.com"
```

output

```
Details are sss: 123 - Total value 100
Some extra variables:
$address: 42 Terrapin Station, $phone: 999-999-9999, $url: http://www.example.com
```

Comment: it gives me "Error: bad expression, please check expression syntax" for the yq command

Comment: Can you post an example somewhere?

Comment: https://github.com/sanurah/yamlexample
I used the same code. Could it be something in my local environment? may be bash version

Comment: What version of yq are you using?

Comment: yq version is 4.29.2

Comment: I'm using yq 3.1.0. I'll try upgrading and see if I can I can reproduce the error.

Comment: I've upgraded to yq 4.29.2 and now I'm seeing `Error: bad expression, please check expression syntax`. I'll need to change the yq expression for version 4 and above.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to play around with it but could not fix. If you find a solution please update the answer for new versions.

Comment: Added support for yq 4 and above. The yq command is a lot cleaner now. Thanks for your report! Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: nice. that worked

Answer (score 2):

There is a cli tool [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) to parse yaml files.

The script would look like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
name=$(yq '.variables.name' data.yaml)
pass=$(yq '.variables.pass' data.yaml)
count=$(yq '.variables.count' data.yaml)

echo "Details are $name: $pass - Total value $count"
```

Of course you can also pass the file as argument.

Comment: is there any other solution without using any other tool/cli @gindex

Comment: @rowoc YAML is complex so there's no general solution other than using a specialised tool for parsing it; that said, if your input is as simple as what you're showing in the question then you can do the job with other (basic/standard) tools

Comment: Yes, there are more options how to parse yaml on [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014632/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-from-a-linux-shell-script), but yq is most simple one. yq is widely adopted also. Why you cannot use it?

Comment: @gindex can you recheck your solution , I tried that not working

Comment: Should work now. Please check the name of the local file and in the script .

Comment: Thanks its working, can the code be minimize, I am having more varaibles, for each i have to again write yq '.variables.xxxx' data.yml . Any minification can be done @gindex

Comment: I have tried this also but its only taking last 3 variable, if i have more data,its takes last 3 only.     
. <(sed -nr '/variables:/,$ s/  ([A-Z_]+): (.*)/\1=\2/ p' .data.yml)

Comment: @rowoc If you need a solution that will scale smoothly, you might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71393380/fetch-variables-values-from-yml-and-pass-to-shell-script/71402938#71402938 "support an arbitrary number of variables").

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single call to `yq` and put values in an array :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
mapfile -t array < <(yq '.variables[]' data.yml)
declare -p array
```