# Get variables from a a file in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file name inputfile having following data:

```
 database=mydb
 table=mytable
 partitions=p1,p2,p3
```

I pass this file as first argument as following:

```
 bash mybashfile.sh inputfile
```

I want to use this file in my bash script that input database, table and partitions as variables

I tried this by putting the whole content of myfile in a variable

```
  #!/bin/bash
  var=$(cat $1) 
  echo $var
```

I am new to bash script so I need help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `source`, which will load the variables from that file

```
#!/bin/bash
source "$1"
echo "$database"
# mydb
echo "$table"
# mytable
echo "$partitons"
# p1,p2,p3
```

For more information about `source` see this [superuser-question](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do)

Comment: If I need to input these variables using yaml file like database: mydb table: MYTABLE  partitions: p1,p2,p3 . Any idea how can I do that

Comment: `source <(sed -e 's/:[^:\/\/]/="/g;s/$/"/g;s/ *=/=/g' file.yaml)` would be a possible solution, but it is not that good or safe to use. Better use a tool like `yq`. For more information about parsing `yaml` to `bash` see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014632/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-from-a-linux-shell-script

Answer (score 0):

You can read key, value pairs from a file with a `while` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A kv     # declare an associative array

while IFS="=" read -r k v; do
    kv["$k"]="$v"
done < "file"

declare -p kv     # print the array
```

Prints:

```
declare -A kv=([table]="mytable" [database]="mydb" [partitions]="p1,p2,p3" )
```