# How to parse YAML file with array inside using bash script

Tags: bash, parsing, yaml

Have a some problem with parsing one special YAML file.
I have a file:

```
country:
 city:
  clients:
    - name: 1
      url: https://google.com
    - name: 2
      url: https://google.com
    - name: 3
```

Have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function parse_yaml {``
   local prefix=$2
   local s='[[:space:]]*' w='[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*' fs=$(echo @ |tr @ '\034')
   sed -ne "s|^\($s\):|\1|" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s[\"']\(.*\)[\"']$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\(.*\)$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" $1 |
   awk -F$fs '{
      indent = length($1)/2;
      vname[indent] = $2;
      for (i in vname) {if (i > indent) {delete vname[i]}}
      if (length($3) > 0) {
         vn=""; for (i=0; i<indent; i++) {vn=(vn)(vname[i])("_")}
         printf ("%s%s%s: \"%s\"\n", "'$prefix'",toupper(vn), toupper($2), $3);
      }
   }'
}
```

What can I do in this script, to parse file who has array inside?

Example what I need:

```
county_city_clients_url[0]: 1
county_city_clients_url[0]: https://google.com
county_city_clients_url[1]: 2
county_city_clients_url[1]: https://google.com
county_city_clients_url[2]: 3
county_city_clients_url[2]: https://google.com
```

Comment: Why not use something like [`yq`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/)? Rewriting YAML parsing yourself in sed/awk is a lot of work.

Comment: If you use someone else's code, give credit to where it's due: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21189044/6890912

Comment: Unless you want to rewrite a YAML processor, you should use one that is already written. [Both implementations of yq](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) would be a good choice, and can perfectly be intergrated into a shell script. For example, using [kislyuk/yq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), this would be one way: `yq -r 'paths(scalars) as $p | "\($p | map(numbers |= "[\(.)]") | join("_")): \(getpath($p))"'`. Btw, in the sample input, the third item misses the url you're expecting in the output.

Comment: Don't ask how to parse *exactly this* file, that doesn't make sense (you could hard-code the values in the script if you only want to support exactly these values). Instead, describe which parts of the structure are static or assumed: Are there always three items in the list? Are the strings always unquoted? Are you only interested in values in`country`-`city`-`clients` or in other values as well? Can there be lists at other nesting depths? Can your strings be multiline? YAML allows all this and it is not clear which of these features you need to parse.

Comment: I understand that sometimes you can't install the right tool and just have to make do with the tools you have but you never need sed when you're using awk and that code is doing some strange, cludgy and/or fragile things (e.g. `fs=$(echo @ |tr @ '\034')` instead of just `fs=$'\034'` and letting the shell variable `$prefix` expand unquoted to become part of the awk script instead of passing in a variable value), its not a good starting point for whatever it is you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended to be a full YAML parser but it seems to do what you want for the example you provided and maybe it'll be useful for others who don't have and can't install YAML-aware tools.

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    match($0,/^ *-? *[^# ]/) {
        prevIndent = currIndent
        if ( RLENGTH in numChars2indent ) {
            currIndent = numChars2indent[RLENGTH]
        }
        else {
            numChars2indent[RLENGTH] = ++currIndent
        }

        if ( currIndent <= prevIndent ) {
            prt()
        }

        data = substr($0,RLENGTH)
        match(data,/ *: */)
        tags[currIndent] = substr(data,1,RSTART-1)
        vals[currIndent] = substr(data,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    END { prt() }

    function prt(   i,tag,val) {
        for ( i=1; i<prevIndent; i++ ) {
            printf "%s_", tags[i]
        }
        tag = tags[prevIndent]
        val = vals[prevIndent]
        printf "%s[%d]: %s\n", tag, ++tagCnt[tag], val
    }
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
country_city_clients_name[1]: 1
country_city_clients_url[1]: https://google.com
country_city_clients_name[2]: 2
country_city_clients_url[2]: https://google.com
country_city_clients_name[3]: 3
```

I'm assuming you don't really expect `county_city_clients_url[2]: https://google.com` in the output since it's not present in the input.

If you want to add functionality to let it read multi-line strings then copy `readRec()` from [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk/45420607#45420607), massage it to suit however multi-line strings are delimited in your YAML files if necessary (if they're all enclosed in double quotes with no individual double quotes in between then `readRec()` won't need any changes), and call it as the first line of the awk script just like it's used on that reference page.